# Squiggly arrows in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

Is it possible to get a path in tikz that looks like `\rightsquigarrow`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is possible, indeed. You can use the `decorations.pathmorphing` library for this, which allows very fine control over how your paths look:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\rightsquigarrow$

\tikz \draw [->,
line join=round,
decorate, decoration={
    zigzag,
    segment length=4,
    amplitude=.9,post=lineto,
    post length=2pt
}]  (0,0) -- (0.3,0);
\end{document}
```

[image: rightsquigarrow and tikz equivalent]

Comment: Thanks! The things one can do in tikz never cease to amaze me.

Comment: would you be so kind as to adjust your code so that your TikZ fake arrow has the same vertical positioning as the genuine `\rightsquigarrow`? Currently it sits too low if I use it inline with text around it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Jake's and Caramdir's solution, here is a bit of height-adjustment based on [egreg's answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275374/what-is-the-local-height-of-a-capital-letter).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newlength{\LETTERheight}
\AtBeginDocument{\settoheight{\LETTERheight}{I}}
\newcommand*{\longleadsto}[1]{\ \raisebox{0.24\LETTERheight}{\tikz \draw [->,
line join=round,
decorate, decoration={
    zigzag,
    segment length=4,
    amplitude=.9,
    post=lineto,
    post length=2pt
}] (0,0) -- (#1,0);}\ }

\begin{document}
$A\leadsto A$

$A\longleadsto{0.5} A$

$A\longleadsto{1} A$
\end{document}
```