# What are the relative strengths of TikZ and Asymptote?

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote, comparison

I want to compare TikZ and Asymptote for their abilities in 2D & 3D functional plot and other general purpose, simple drawings.

What are the strong aspects of TikZ over Asymptote?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I've used both and I prefer TikZ.

- TikZ and `asymptote` are equally powerful, but programming in `asymptote` is easier.
- TikZ has styles which can be used to enforce a consistent look and feel. For example, you can define a style for help lines. In `asymptote` you don't have styles.
- `asymptote` can only be used by writing an `asymptote` program, generating a picture, and including the picture. You cannot reference what's in the picture. With TikZ it's different. You can define a label in certain kinds of TikZ pictures and reference it in another TikZ picture. This allows you to draw lines from one specific part of a TikZ picture to another part of a `TikZ` picture or to specific positions of the page (centre, north, south west, ...). As another example, you can define the baseline of TikZ pictures so you can align them neatly.
- To see the advantage of the previous point, consider the `pgfkeys` package,  which provides some really useful tools for parsing key=value lists. Even if you don't want to draw anything, your LaTeX code can benefit from the package. Joseph Wright has made `pgfkeys`-style parsing available in class and packages with his `pgfopts` package. It's difficult to see how your LaTeX programming can benefit from the (external) `asymptote` program (except by allowing shell escapes, which is asking for troubles). Another interesting development is TikZ's object oriented programming, which I'd like to explore a bit further when I have more time. (In fact, exploring the TikZ/`pgf` manual properly is something on the top of my list....)
- A TikZ picture sits in the same environment as the main LaTeX document, so any LaTeX command that's used in TikZ uses the same definitions as the main LaTeX document. With `asymptote` this is not the case and you have to do extra work to tell `asymptote` about the definitions of the LaTeX commands. This is really important to me because I frequently use the `beamer` package in different modes. Depending on the modes, different fonts are used in the output. With TikZ the font is picked up automatically. Letting `asymptote` do this requires extra work.

Comment: Equally powerful ?? I'm not sure. I like Tikz and I use only this package but Asymptote seems to be more powerful ( for example 3D)

Comment: @AlainMatthes I am speaking in terms of what they can do, not how they do it. For example, in this sense a Turing machine is equally powerful as the lambda calculus. TikZ can draw curves and a all that's needed for a 2D representation of a 3D picture are curves. In that sense, TikZ is equally powerful as any package/program that can draw 3D.

Comment: @AlainMatthes Further to my previous comment. I mentioned in my answer that Asymptote provides an easier programming environment.

Comment: I think this answer misses an important point : `Asymptote` can do some things that `tikz` cannot (see other answers below). (And conversely.)

Comment: @anderstood You may have missed the first point:-) They're all equally strong in the sense that any picture that can be drawn with one system can also be drawn with another.

Comment: OK, but you can build examples such that programming time diverges for tikz. I think this remark, though technically true, might be misunderstood.

Comment: @anderstood And if it will be misunderstood it will not be for the first time. See my comment to Alain Matthes:-)

Comment: "In asymptote you don't have styles." -- this is not strictly true either, you can define a custom pen like `pen helplines = gray+dashed;` then use it in drawing commands `draw((0, 0)--(1, 1), helplines)`.

Answer (score 43):

By request, I'm turning my comment into an answer.

I very much like the [`tikz-3dplot`](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-3dplot/tikz-3dplot_documentation.pdf) package, which appends to tikz' 3D capabilities.

You should really go trough the manual to see what it's capable of, but here are some examples:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\newcommand{\ve}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ud}[0]{\mathrm{d}}

\tikzset{
    vector/.style = {
        thick,
        > = stealth',
    },
    axis/.style = {
        very thin,
        > = stealth',
    },
}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=0.8]

    % draw axes
    \draw[axis,->] (0,0,0) coordinate (O) -- (5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$}; 
    \draw[axis,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,4.95,0) node[right,anchor=west]{$y$}; 
    \draw[axis,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4.95) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

    % draw 
    \draw[vector,->] (O) -- node[above left]{\ve{v}} (2,4,3) coordinate (V);
    \draw[vector,->] (O) -- node[below right]{$\ve{v}_x$}(2,0,0)node[left]{$2$};
    \draw[vector,->] (O) -- node[below]{$\ve{v}_y$}(0,4,0)node[below right]{$4$};
    \draw[vector,->] (O) -- node[left]{$\ve{v}_z$}(0,0,3)node[above left]{$3$};

    \draw[densely dotted] (0,4,0) -- (2,4,0) -- (2,0,0);
    \draw[densely dotted] (V) -- (0,4,3) -- (0,0,3) -- (2,0,3) -- (2,0,0);
    \draw[densely dotted] (2,0,3) -- (V) -- (2,4,0);
    \draw[densely dotted] (0,4,0) -- (0,4,3);

    \foreach \s in{1,2,3,4}{
        \draw[fill](\s,0,0)circle(0.5pt);
        \draw[fill](0,\s,0)circle(0.5pt);
        \draw[fill](0,0,\s)circle(0.5pt);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\bigskip

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{120}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{90}{90}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=0.5]
    \draw (0,0,0) -- ++(0,-2.3,0) node[above left]{$-$};

    % draw a condensor plate
    \draw[fill=lightgray] (-1.5,0,-1.5)--(-1.5,0,1.5)--(1.5,0,1.5)--(1.5,0,-1.5)--cycle;
    \draw[fill=lightgray] (1.5,0,-1.5)--(1.5,-0.2,-1.5)--(1.5,-0.2,1.5)--(1.5,0,1.5)--cycle;
    \draw[fill=lightgray] (1.5,-0.2,1.5)--(-1.5,-0.2,1.5)--(-1.5,0,1.5)--(1.5,0,1.5)--cycle;

    \def\q{-2.3}

    % draw surface
    \draw (0,-0.5*\q,0) coordinate(R);
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords,fill opacity=0.5,fill=lightgray!30,draw=black]{(R)}{3}{0}{360}{}{}
    \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords](R)++(-110:3) node[below left]{$S_2$};
    \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords](R)++(70:3) node[above right]{$C$};

    % draw second condensor plate
    \draw[fill=lightgray] (-1.5,0-\q,-1.5)--(-1.5,0-\q,1.5)--(1.5,0-\q,1.5)--(1.5,0-\q,-1.5)--cycle;
    \draw[fill=lightgray] (1.5,0-\q,-1.5)--(1.5,-0.2-\q,-1.5)--(1.5,-0.2-\q,1.5)--(1.5,0-\q,1.5)--cycle;
    \draw[fill=lightgray] (1.5,-0.2-\q,1.5)--(-1.5,-0.2-\q,1.5)--(-1.5,0-\q,1.5)--(1.5,0-\q,1.5)--cycle;
    \draw (0,-\q,0)--++(0,2,0)node[above right]{$+$};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=0.5]
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{90}{90}%

    \draw (0,0,0)--++(0,-2.3,0)node[above left]{$-$};

    % draw condensore plate
    \draw[fill=lightgray] (-1.5,0,-1.5)--(-1.5,0,1.5)--(1.5,0,1.5)--(1.5,0,-1.5)--cycle;
    \draw[fill=lightgray] (1.5,0,-1.5)--(1.5,-0.2,-1.5)--(1.5,-0.2,1.5)--(1.5,0,1.5)--cycle;
    \draw[fill=lightgray] (1.5,-0.2,1.5)--(-1.5,-0.2,1.5)--(-1.5,0,1.5)--(1.5,0,1.5)--cycle;

    % draw surface
    \def\q{-2.3}
    \def\R{3}
    \draw (0,-0.5*\q,0) coordinate(R);
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords,fill=lightgray,fill opacity=0.5,draw=black]{(R)}{\R}{0}{360}{}{}
    \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords](R)++(-110:\R) node[below left]{$S_1$};
    \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords](R)++(70:\R) node[above right]{$C$};
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{70}{90}
    \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords](R)++(90:\R) coordinate (A) circle(0.5pt);
    \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords,fill opacity=0.5,fill=lightgray!30](A)arc(90:270:\R);
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{90}{90}
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords,fill=lightgray!10,draw=black]{(R)}{\R}{0}{360}{}{}
    \begin{scope}

    % draw condensor plate again, inside (clip outside)
    \clip[tdplot_rotated_coords] (R)++(0:\R) arc (0:360:\R);
    \draw[fill=lightgray] (-1.5,0,-1.5)--(-1.5,0,1.5)--(1.5,0,1.5)--(1.5,0,-1.5)--cycle;
    \draw[fill=lightgray] (1.5,0,-1.5)--(1.5,-0.2,-1.5)--(1.5,-0.2,1.5)--(1.5,0,1.5)--cycle;
    \draw[fill=lightgray] (1.5,-0.2,1.5)--(-1.5,-0.2,1.5)--(-1.5,0,1.5)--(1.5,0,1.5)--cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords] (R)++(0:\R) arc (0:360:\R);

    % draw second condensor plate
    \draw[fill=lightgray] (-1.5,0-\q,-1.5)--(-1.5,0-\q,1.5)--(1.5,0-\q,1.5)--(1.5,0-\q,-1.5)--cycle;
    \draw[fill=lightgray] (1.5,0-\q,-1.5)--(1.5,-0.2-\q,-1.5)--(1.5,-0.2-\q,1.5)--(1.5,0-\q,1.5)--cycle;
    \draw[fill=lightgray] (1.5,-0.2-\q,1.5)--(-1.5,-0.2-\q,1.5)--(-1.5,0-\q,1.5)--(1.5,0-\q,1.5)--cycle;
    \draw (0,-\q,0)--++(0,2,0)node[above right]{$+$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\bigskip

\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{120} 
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{90}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=1.6]
    % praw circular plate
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords,fill=lightgray,draw=lightgray,line width=0pt]{(0,-0.5,0)}{1}{0}{360}{}{}
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords,fill=lightgray]{(0,-0.5,0)}{1}{180}{360}{}{}
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords,fill=lightgray]{(0,0,0)}{1}{0}{360}{}{}
    \draw[yshift=1cm](0,0)--(0.5,0);
    \draw[yshift=-1cm](0,0)--(0.5,0);

    \draw[help lines] (0,0,0)--(-9,0,0)node[right]{$s$};
    \draw[help lines] (-6,0,0)--(-6,0,1.5);
    \draw[fill](-6,0,0) circle (0.5pt) node[above,fill=white]{$P(a)$}node[below]{$q$};
    \draw[fill](-6,0,0) circle (0.5pt);

    % draw inner circle
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords,help lines]{(0,0,0)}{0.6}{0}{360}{}{}
    \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords,<->](0,0,0)--node[below]{$r$}(0.05,-0.6);
    \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords,<->](0,0,0)--node[right]{$R$}(0.7,0.7);

    % dtheta angle
    \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords](-0.42,-0.42,0)--(-0.57,-0.57,0);
    \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords](-0.6,0,0)--(-0.8,0,0);
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.8}{180}{225}{}{}
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.6}{180}{225}{}{}

    \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords,help lines](0,0,0)--(-1.1,-1.1,0);
    \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords,help lines](0,0,0)--(-1.5,0,0);
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords,<->]{(0,0,0)}{1.4}{180}{225}{above left}{$\ud\theta$}

    % annotate stuff
    \draw[tdplot_rotated_coords] (-0.65,-0.25,0) coordinate (X);
    \draw[vector,->] (X)--node[above]{$x$}(-6,0,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,0,1.2)--node[above]{$a$}(-6,0,1.2);
    \draw (-0.2,0,-1) node[right]{$S$};
    \draw[vector,->] (-6,0,0)--(-7,0,0)node[below]{$\ve{K}$};
    \draw[vector,->] (-6,0,0)--(-8,0,0)node[below]{$\ve{E}$};
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{90}{90}
    \draw(-6,0,0) coordinate (Q);
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(Q)}{1.2}{170}{180}{left}{$\phi$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(note that the above code is just copy pasted code, sometimes from pretty old documents, so it may be that there is some inefficient code in there, from when I wasn't that good at TikZ yet).
Compiling the above document gives you these figures:
[image: euclidian space]
[image: condensator]
[image: gauss law]

You can do pretty much everything it TikZ although sometimes it gets pretty hairy to get there. I remember I once drew the Stern Gerlach experiment in 3D (strangely shaped magnets, and their field lines) but I lost the code to that. [TeXample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/3d/) also has a 3D category, which holds numerous examples of 3D images that can be done in TikZ.

Answer (score 41):

TikZ always won for me, though it's great that there are alternative ways with Asymptote.

I would prefer

- TikZ for drawing diagrams, graphs, trees, especially when the focus is on typesetting;
- Asymptote only if heavy math or algorithms are required, which could be when plotting - even then I can use TikZ with Gnuplot.

Reasons:

- TikZ works integrated with LaTeX, TeX and ConTeXt, you can use your macros in TikZ drawings and plots. In contrast, Asymptote doesn't have access to your (La)TeX macros.
- TikZ is programmed in TeX. Extending it requires TeX programming, which is not easy to use as programming language. In contrast, Asymptote is written in C and provides a language similar to C, C++ and Java for programming it, which may make programming easier.
- Asymptote provides many [mathematical functions](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Mathematical-functions.html#Mathematical-functions) and numerical routines, and is in this regard in my opinion more powerful than TikZ with its floating point unit library.

Comment: Asymptote does have access to (La)TeX macros, 
when used as an inline environment inside (La)TeX document.

Comment: @g.kov you should add your `asy` answer here based on your experience in 2D and [3D](http://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0010448511001291-gr5.jpg) [example](http://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0010448511001291-gr11.jpg) to help others as 3D is not covered.

Answer (score 41):

This is an old post, but I think the answers do not underline strongly enough that sometimes, Asymptote cannot be avoided, because of the lack of real 3D support, as indicated by [Count Zero](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40292/34258).

More precisely, if I am not mistaken, `tikz-3dplot` and other LaTeX packages adds elements as they appear in the code. What if one element should sometimes be in the foreground *and* sometimes in the background? Well, it does not work.

Two examples to illustrate my point:

- one from TeXample: [link](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/dandelin-spheres/) When you watch carefully the black volume, you see that it is always behind the other curves, which should not. This might be acceptable there, but more generally it can be a serious drawback.
- another example of my own (with `pgfplots`), were  the blue curves erroneously overlay the red ones:

[image: example of wrong 3D hidden parts]

Also, the possibility of embedding 3D objects in `pdf` gives a great advantage to Asymptote: manipulating 3D plots interactively, with the mouse, within pdf files (see *prc* for more information). See e.g. [this file](http://www.pakin.org/~scott/asymptote_export/blender_asymptote.pdf), unfortunately to be opened only with Adobe Reader 9+. Note that the 3D objects has to be rasterized when doing so, as far as I know.

**EDIT** To illustrate my first point, this is a slightly different view of the same 3D object, with `Asymptote`. The main thing to look at are the curves being sometimes on top, sometimes behind, which was the major defect with Tikz and pgfplots.

[image: with Asymptote]

Small summary based on my recent experience:

`Tikz`:

- PRO: somehow simpler
- CON: false 3D, objects are either entirely in the foreground, or entirely in the background

`Asymptote`:

- PRO: real 3D
- PRO: both perspective or orthotropic views are possible
- PRO: possibility to embed 3D objects in pdf with `prc`
- CON: rasterizing required
- CON: rendering sometimes include unwanted black stripes (there are some solutions to avoid this, but it slows down the work-flow)

To make it simple, I would recommend using Tikz and pgfplots as long as it feeds your needs, and swap to asymptote otherwise!

Comment: What you describe as `false 3d` is the unfortunate missing feature of `z buffering` in `pgfplots`, see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227929/pgfplots-z-buffer-does-not-sort-the-plotted-objects-properly. In fact, `pgfplots` has a `z buffer`, but it only works within one object and not between objects. So for instance, one surface with a part of it behind another part of it works. But two surfaces intersecting each other wont work.

I hope a good `z buffer` will be included in `pgfplots` soon. Along with `light sources`, I consider `z buffer` an indispensable feature for 3d pics.

Answer (score 32):

**Updates:**

- To my great surprise, Christian Feuersänger has managed to include Bezier surfaces in his wonderful `pgfplots` package; see his comment below. I still much prefer the Asymptote-style lighting, which is more "realistic"; as of this writing, `pgfplots` supports colormaps (i.e., colors determined by a user-supplied function on three-dimensional space) and explicitly described colors, but cannot compute light and shade.
- Concerning documentation: I have been writing a [tutorial](http://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf) for Asymptote that is modeled on the first TikZ tutorial (but not, I hope, to the point of plagiarism). I believe the chapter on two-dimensional drawing is complete enough to be usable, and much more user-friendly than the official Asympote manual. The three-dimensional chapters have a ways to go, but I dare to hope they are already helpful. Feedback is appreciated.

---

I would like to add a few points that do not seem to have been brought up yet:

- Documentation: The `TikZ` documentation is fabulous. The `Asymptote` documentation is okay, but could be significantly more user-friendly. And there are many aspects of `Asymptote` that are not documented except in the source code.
- Modularity: It is much easier and more natural to define things with names like `a`, `b`, and `f` in Asymptote without fear that these will somehow interfere with something else. It's also easier to create an object and then use it in several different ways, although I imagine the `TikZ` situation here will improve once the object-oriented aspects are more fully integrated into the documentation.
- Bezier surfaces: Using Asymptote, it is possible to draw a complicated 3D surface that appears perfectly smooth (no corners where grid lines meet). I can't imagine that any TeX-based drawing program will ever be able to imitate this feat, even calling gnuplot. Likewise, Asymptote can provide complex shading (with specularity, etc.) that is almost certainly beyond the scope of TikZ or any TeX-based system. See, for instance, the picture of the Klein bottle at [the Asymptote gallery](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/).

Comment: `pgfplots` as tikz library supports complicated and smooth 3d surfaces in a very simple and elegant way by means of its `surf` and `shader` keys which do a very good job for standard visualizations, compare http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97502/2d-colors-above-3d-surface-plot/97504#97504. For advanced stuff see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99133/creating-bezier-surfaces-using-procedural-graphics/102585#102585

Comment: Do Janet's students care about dashing patterns as Karl's students don't?

Comment: Are you referring at Sec. 4.27 of `pgfplots`' documentation? It does not mean background and foreground are properly handled, right?

Comment: @anderstood: No, I'm not referring to Section 4.27. But in any case, you are correct that background and foreground are not properly handled by `pgfplots`.

Answer (score 9):

I'm afraid I'm also partial to `TikZ`... `:)`

In addition to the arguments listed, I'd like to add one in favor of `Asymptote`, though: it has real 3D support, something `TikZ` lacks. (But will have one day, hopefully.)

Comment: I like [`tikz-3dplot`](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-3dplot/tikz-3dplot_documentation.pdf). It is a package that allows some pretty powerful 3d drawing in tikz. I've managed to do some awesome drawing using it.

Comment: @romeovs: Would you mind submitting the drawings you mentioned to [TeXample.net](http://texample.net/)? As Count Zero mentioned, 3D stuff is not TikZ' strongest point, so it would be good to see examples of what's possible nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Asymptote has built-in scaling, [TikZ needs the `tikzscale` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75449/specifying-the-width-and-height-of-a-tikzpicture)

#### Asymptote

Syntax: [`size(6cm)`](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/doc/Figure-size.html#index-size) (make the picture as large as possible while the width and the height is at most 6cm)

- The feature is quite in-built in the language, however there are some counterintuitive behavior.

  - One is:

    ```
    unitsize(1cm);
    draw((0, 0)--(1+1mm, 1));
    ```

    This compiles, but doesn't do what you expect --- in Asymptote, `1+1mm` equals ≈ `3.835`. ([reason](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/doc/Implicit-scaling.html).)

    In TikZ, you can do `\draw (0, 0) -- (1, 1) coordinate [xshift=1mm] (a) -- (a);` instead.

    In order to place objects at absolute location, you need *deferred drawing routine*. (Or turn off the built-in scaling feature entirely, or reimplement the equivalent of it)

    > And there are many aspects of Asymptote that are not documented except in the source code.

    Deferred drawing is one of the aspects that is not documented https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/issues/425
  - Another one: **In TikZ you can easily get the rightmost/leftmost point etc. of a label/node** in order to draw a figure such as:

    [image]

    In Asymptote, **you need to disable automatic scaling or enable deferred drawing**.
    Refer to [Commutative diagrams using MetaPost or Asymptote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7247/250119) for an example.

    **Personally, this issue is quite difficult for me. A lot of documentation-reading is needed to understand what is going on.**

    In a similar vein, the concept of nodes in TikZ are also nontrivial in Inkscape --- the equivalent is `envelope`, refer to [Handy TikZ's `node` version in Asymptote?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/575512/250119) ---
    but it only works well when neither `unitsize` nor `size` is specified (i.e. unit is `bp`)

    Also, `\strut` etc. need to be manually specified. Example:

    ```tex
    object a=draw("\strut a", box, xmargin=0.2cm, ymargin=0.1cm, (0, 0));
    object b=draw("\strut b", box, xmargin=0.2cm, ymargin=0.1cm, (3cm, 0));
    draw(point(a, right)--point(b, left), Arrow);
    ```

    See also the question linked above.

    [image]

#### `tikzscale`

Syntax: `\includegraphics[width=6cm]{image.tikz}`

- Needs an external `.tikz` file. (This is fixable, but the package by itself doesn't support this)
- There is a bit of feature creep: if `currfile` package is included then it will also handle relative import of files. ([normally this is handled by `\graphicspath` or `import` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4602/250119).)
- The command `\includegraphics` is patched, so it is likely to clash with other commands that also patch `\includegraphics`.
- The `tikzscale` package works by *measuring the tikzpicture with two different scalings* (quoted from the documentation), which involves running the body multiple times.
  Which implies:

  - Footnote counting is wrong. In the example below, the footnote mark is numbered 5 instead of 1.

    ```tex
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tikzscale}
    \usepackage{footnotehyper}
    \makesavenoteenv{tikzpicture}
    \begin{document}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{image.tikz}
    \end{document}
    % image.tikz contains:
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 2);
        \node at (0, 0) {Text\footnote{Footnote text}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    ```
  - Other uses of counters will break. (Technically, if special measures are applied like being done in `align*` environments, it can be made to partially work. The package does not handle that, however)

    ```tex
    % image.tikz contains:
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 2);
        \node at (0, 0) {%
            \addtocounter{mycounter}{1}%
            $x=\arabic{mycounter}$.
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    ```

### 2. TikZ can easily get the rightmost/leftmost point of a label/node, Asymptote requires deferred drawing or disabling automatic scaling

Already mentioned above.

### 3. Asymptote use `align=up` or `align=N`, TikZ use `anchor=south`

On the other hand TikZ also has shorthands like `edge quotes` to put text next to path,
or `[right] [right=of a] [left] [above] [below] [anchor=south]` etc.

### 4. TikZ has more built-in libraries, Asymptote makes it easier to write your own

e.g. TikZ has [a built-in library to draw a zigzag line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12680/250119),
and [you can write one in Asymptote in ≈ 15 lines of code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12696/250119).

(This is just one example, but given that Asymptote documentation is ≈200 pages and TikZ documentation is >1000 pages, this appears to be likely.)

### 5. Asymptote has `dot` which by default lies on top of everything

Just a minor point, since it can be implemented in TikZ without too much difficulty.

In Asymptote, `dot(<coordinate>)` draws a dot at that coordinate, but by default, if you draw some line subsequently, **the dot will always be in front**.

For TikZ, there is an option of using `pic` and `pgfonlayer` for that. [How to draw points in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/217797/250119)

### 6. Documentation

#### Asymptote

As mentioned, one of the issues with Asymptote documentation is that many important features are undocumented. For example, regarding the example of "node" (envelope) above,

- `pair point(object F, pair dir, transform t=identity())` is completely undocumented.
- the `object` type itself is barely documented.
- Another issue is that Asymptote functions are heavily overloaded, and it's **not simple** to find which section of the documentation corresponds to the appropriate overload, or even if that overload variant is documented at all.

#### TikZ

The user-level documentation is quite good --- there is also a HTML version https://tikz.dev/ (maintained by different author).
The HTML version also has ctrl-K to search (powered by Algolia DocSearch), which is quite reasonable.

The search engine is not the best though. For instance, searching for `-|` or `..` doesn't come up with good result, and search for `dashed` just go to the start of section 15.3.2 instead of the correct anchor.

Answer (score 0):

The great strength of Assymptote is that it allows you to create 3D images that can be manipulated with the mouse, as this example shows (from my question here : [Asymptote 3d: Remove the flicker from the dots of a dice to play?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/379969/138900))

Tikz allows it to manage the nodes and texts added to graphics more finely.

**This is a 6-sided die that can be rotated with the mouse.**

```
import three;
currentprojection =orthographic((5,2,3));
currentlight=nolight;
settings.tex="latex"; // Moteur LaTeX utilisé pour la compilation (latex, pdflatex, ...)
settings.outformat="pdf"; // Format de sortie ; eps par défaut
settings.prc=true; // Format PRC de la figure ; vrai par défaut
settings.render=-1; // Rendu des figures ; -1 par défaut
size(6cm,0);
real a = 0.05;
path    carre = box ((0,0),(84a,84a)),
      disque = scale(9a)*unitcircle,
      patron1[] = shift(42a,42a)*disque,
      patron2[] = shift(14a,70a)*disque^^shift(70a,14a)*disque,
      patron3[] = shift(14a,70a)*disque^^shift(70a,14a)*disque^^shift(42a,42a)*disque,
      patron4[] = shift(14a,14a)*disque^^shift(14a,70a)*disque^^shift(70a,14a)*disque^^shift(70a,70a)*disque,
      patron5[] = shift(14a,14a)*disque^^shift(14a,70a)*disque^^shift(70a,14a)*disque^^shift(70a,70a)*disque^^shift(42a,42a)*disque,
      patron6[] = shift(14a,14a)*disque^^shift(14a,70a)*disque^^shift(70a,14a)*disque^^shift(70a,70a)*disque^^shift(42a,70a)*disque^^shift(42a,14a)*disque;
transform3 tX=shift((84a+00.1)*X), tY=shift((84a+.001)*Y), tZ=shift((84a+0.01)*Z);      
path3    facegauche[] =shift(0,-0.001,0)*path3(patron6,ZXplane),
      facedroite[] =path3(patron1,ZXplane),
      faceavant[] =path3(patron2,YZplane),
      facearriere[] =shift(-0.001,0,0)*path3(patron5,YZplane),   
      facehaut[] =path3(patron4,XYplane),      
      facebas[] =shift(0,0,-0.001)*path3(patron3,XYplane);      
draw(scale3(84a)*unitcube, surfacepen=white);
draw(box(O, 84a*(X+Y+Z)), gray);
draw(surface(facegauche),blue);
draw(surface(tY*facedroite),blue);
draw(surface(tZ*facehaut),blue);
draw(surface(facebas),blue);
draw(surface(facearriere),blue);
draw(surface(tX*faceavant),blue);
```