# Where is the pattern list gallery for pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Where is the list, or gallery of the patterns available for pgfplots?

Answer (score 66):

The pattern list itself is not directly related to pgfplots, but to tikz and pgf. The pattern list is available at section 26 "Pattern Library", of "TikZ and pgf Manual".

Or at page 217 of:http://paws.wcu.edu/tsfoguel/tikzpgfmanual.pdf

The current list of patterns listed at manual version 1.18:

- horizontal lines
- vertical lines
- north east lines
- north west lines
- grid
- crosshatch
- dots
- crosshatch dots
- fivepointed stars
- sixpointed stars

Comment: In addition to the patterns of TikZ, pgfplots adds a couple of shading patterns generated by its `surf` plot handler. A good overview is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99133/creating-bezier-surfaces-using-procedural-graphics/102585#102585 . These shadings cannot be generated by pgf/TikZ.