# pgfplots: How to smoothen a 3D surface plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d, tikz-3d, smooth

Long time has passed - based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141825/pgfplots-how-to-smoothen-up-a-surface-plot-with-coordinates) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118131/how-to-plot-a-surface-from-a-set-of-data) question I would like to know if `pgfplots` does already support surface smoothening of coordinate based 3D plots in 2019?

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.csv}
    x;y;z
    0;0;4
    0;1;4
    0;2;4
    1;0;2
    1;1;2
    1;2;2
    2;0;3
    2;1;3
    2;2;3
    3;0;0
    3;1;0
    3;2;0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[table/col sep = semicolon]
            \addplot3[mesh, mesh/cols=3,surf, shader=interp] table[x=x, y=y, z=z] {testdata.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Screenshot of the desired state:**

[image: Screenshot of the desired state]

---

As you can see, the desired state represents some beautiful `grid lines` as well as smoothened curves instead of rough peaks. Is this purely possible with `pgfplots` nowadays?

Unfortunately combining `[surf]` and `[smooth]` of a `plot` does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think that, as of now, there is a `smooth` option for surface plots. However, you can smoothen out the table data yourself. As any smoothening, this comes with a prescription and with parameters. If you draw a 1D curve you can specify the tension, so you may want to think of the `\mysigmax` and `\mysigmay` parameters in the following code as serving a similar purpose.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{testdata.csv}
    x;y;z
    0;0;4
    0;1;4
    0;2;4
    1;0;2
    1;1;2
    1;2;2
    2;0;3
    2;1;3
    2;2;3
    3;0;0
    3;1;0
    3;2;0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{testdata.csv}\datatable
  \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Xmax}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\mysum{0}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\mysigmax{0.5}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\mysigmay{0.3}
  \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \X in {0,...,\Xmax}{
     \pgfplotstablegetelem{\X}{x}\of{\datatable}
     \edef\myx{\pgfplotsretval}
     \pgfplotstablegetelem{\X}{y}\of{\datatable}
     \edef\myy{\pgfplotsretval}
     \pgfplotstablegetelem{\X}{z}\of{\datatable}
     \edef\myz{\pgfplotsretval}
     \edef\mysum{\mysum+\myz*exp(-((x-\myx)^2/\mysigmax+(y-\myy)^2/\mysigmay))}
  }
  %\typeout{\mysum}
        \begin{axis}[table/col sep = semicolon]
            %\addplot3[mesh, mesh/cols=3,surf, shader=interp] table[x=x, y=y, z=z] {testdata.csv};
            \addplot3[surf,domain=0:3,domain y=0:2] {\mysum};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you set `\mysigmay` to `3` instead you get

[image]