# Interpolate grid data to obtain 3d smooth surface

Tags: pgfplots

I use this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
ytick={0,0.2,...,1},
xtick={0,0.2,...,1},
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
zlabel={$z$},
xmajorgrids=true,
ymajorgrids=true,
major grid style={dashed},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view/h=45,xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,colorbar horizontal, xlabel style={sloped}, ylabel style={sloped}, colorbar style={xlabel=$z$, xlabel style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-1)}}}]
        \addplot3[surf,shader=faceted interp] table [col sep=comma] {scatter.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

with this `scatter.csv`

```
0.000000,0.000000,50
0.000000,0.020110,2
0.000000,0.021307,0
0.000000,0.250000,5
0.000000,0.333333,3
0.000000,0.500000,22
0.000000,1.000000,1

0.000300,0.000000,2
0.000300,0.020110,0
0.000300,0.021307,0
0.000300,0.250000,0
0.000300,0.333333,0
0.000300,0.500000,0
0.000300,1.000000,0

0.001908,0.000000,2
0.001908,0.020110,0
0.001908,0.021307,0
0.001908,0.250000,0
0.001908,0.333333,0
0.001908,0.500000,0
0.001908,1.000000,0

0.003472,0.000000,2
0.003472,0.020110,0
0.003472,0.021307,0
0.003472,0.250000,0
0.003472,0.333333,0
0.003472,0.500000,0
0.003472,1.000000,0

0.010204,0.000000,3
0.010204,0.020110,0
0.010204,0.021307,0
0.010204,0.250000,0
0.010204,0.333333,0
0.010204,0.500000,0
0.010204,1.000000,0

0.028409,0.000000,2
0.028409,0.020110,0
0.028409,0.021307,0
0.028409,0.250000,0
0.028409,0.333333,0
0.028409,0.500000,0
0.028409,1.000000,0

0.035714,0.000000,0
0.035714,0.020110,0
0.035714,0.021307,2
0.035714,0.250000,0
0.035714,0.333333,0
0.035714,0.500000,0
0.035714,1.000000,0

0.045455,0.000000,1
0.045455,0.020110,0
0.045455,0.021307,0
0.045455,0.250000,0
0.045455,0.333333,0
0.045455,0.500000,2
0.045455,1.000000,0

0.083154,0.000000,0
0.083154,0.020110,0
0.083154,0.021307,0
0.083154,0.250000,0
0.083154,0.333333,0
0.083154,0.500000,2
0.083154,1.000000,0

0.092784,0.000000,0
0.092784,0.020110,0
0.092784,0.021307,0
0.092784,0.250000,0
0.092784,0.333333,0
0.092784,0.500000,2
0.092784,1.000000,0

0.119578,0.000000,2
0.119578,0.020110,0
0.119578,0.021307,0
0.119578,0.250000,0
0.119578,0.333333,0
0.119578,0.500000,0
0.119578,1.000000,0

1.000000,0.000000,1
1.000000,0.020110,0
1.000000,0.021307,0
1.000000,0.250000,0
1.000000,0.333333,0
1.000000,0.500000,4
1.000000,1.000000,68
```

I obtain the following 3D plot

[image]

which is correct, but ugly. I know this results from how my data points are distributed (not uniformly). How can I obtain a smooth surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builtin capabilities of `pgfplots` allow to visualize a data matrix as either triangular surface patches or bilinear surface patches (the latter using `patch type=bilinear`).

Given a suitable data input, it also allows biquadratic and bicubic (i.e. smooth) patches. However, that data input is considerably more complicated. A brief overview of this method is shown in [Creating Bezier surfaces using procedural graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99133/creating-bezier-surfaces-using-procedural-graphics/102585#102585). Note, however, that this method does not work using your input table; the data format would need to be enrichment and reorganization.

In order to improve the quality of your picture, you have two choices: (a) to increase the sampling density of your plot and stick with piecewise linear/piecewise bilinear shading or (b) to keep the sampling density, but increase the order of each patch to biquadratic or bicubic by means of some advanced external tool and import that it into `pgfplots`.

If the question is: "how can I get a smooth surface while keeping the input data", the answer is: `pgfplots` offers at most `patch type=bilinear` (combined with `\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
ytick={0,0.2,...,1},
xtick={0,0.2,...,1},
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
zlabel={$z$},
xmajorgrids=true,
ymajorgrids=true,
major grid style={dashed},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view/h=45,xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,colorbar horizontal, xlabel style={sloped}, ylabel style={sloped}, colorbar style={xlabel=$z$, xlabel style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-1)}}}]
        \addplot3[surf,
            patch type=bilinear,
            shader=faceted interp] table [col sep=comma] {
0.000000,0.000000,50
0.000000,0.020110,2
0.000000,0.021307,0
0.000000,0.250000,5
0.000000,0.333333,3
0.000000,0.500000,22
0.000000,1.000000,1

0.000300,0.000000,2
0.000300,0.020110,0
0.000300,0.021307,0
0.000300,0.250000,0
0.000300,0.333333,0
0.000300,0.500000,0
0.000300,1.000000,0

0.001908,0.000000,2
0.001908,0.020110,0
0.001908,0.021307,0
0.001908,0.250000,0
0.001908,0.333333,0
0.001908,0.500000,0
0.001908,1.000000,0

0.003472,0.000000,2
0.003472,0.020110,0
0.003472,0.021307,0
0.003472,0.250000,0
0.003472,0.333333,0
0.003472,0.500000,0
0.003472,1.000000,0

0.010204,0.000000,3
0.010204,0.020110,0
0.010204,0.021307,0
0.010204,0.250000,0
0.010204,0.333333,0
0.010204,0.500000,0
0.010204,1.000000,0

0.028409,0.000000,2
0.028409,0.020110,0
0.028409,0.021307,0
0.028409,0.250000,0
0.028409,0.333333,0
0.028409,0.500000,0
0.028409,1.000000,0

0.035714,0.000000,0
0.035714,0.020110,0
0.035714,0.021307,2
0.035714,0.250000,0
0.035714,0.333333,0
0.035714,0.500000,0
0.035714,1.000000,0

0.045455,0.000000,1
0.045455,0.020110,0
0.045455,0.021307,0
0.045455,0.250000,0
0.045455,0.333333,0
0.045455,0.500000,2
0.045455,1.000000,0

0.083154,0.000000,0
0.083154,0.020110,0
0.083154,0.021307,0
0.083154,0.250000,0
0.083154,0.333333,0
0.083154,0.500000,2
0.083154,1.000000,0

0.092784,0.000000,0
0.092784,0.020110,0
0.092784,0.021307,0
0.092784,0.250000,0
0.092784,0.333333,0
0.092784,0.500000,2
0.092784,1.000000,0

0.119578,0.000000,2
0.119578,0.020110,0
0.119578,0.021307,0
0.119578,0.250000,0
0.119578,0.333333,0
0.119578,0.500000,0
0.119578,1.000000,0

1.000000,0.000000,1
1.000000,0.020110,0
1.000000,0.021307,0
1.000000,0.250000,0
1.000000,0.333333,0
1.000000,0.500000,4
1.000000,1.000000,68
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Note that your screenshot reveals an outdated/incorrect PDF viewer. The correct output of your minimal working example as you typed it into the question is

[image]

You can verify this by using Acrobat Reader. I know that some old PDF viewers had lousy support for shadings. I would guess that your viewer is `xpdf` or some variant of `libpoppler`. There are more recent versions available which have correct visualization of these shadings. I suggest to upgrade to a more recent viewer.

Comment: I "solved" this by doing some interpolation on the data. I'm using the latest version of the evince viewer on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, so I guess the problem is that is buggy, not outdated...

Comment: OK. sometimes "buggy" and "outdated" is the same -- I am unsure if evince belongs to that category (but I know for sure that `xpdf` and `libpoppler` does - I fixed these viewer bugs on my own).

Comment: Since you actually followed my guidelines (incrased the data accuracy), it might actually help others if you'd accept the answer and post whatever followups you might encounter in new questions.