# Is it possible to expect pst-solides3d (in the future) to generate gradient mesh?

Tags: pst-solides3d, illustrator

I have been using `pst-solides3d` to generate surfaces and then importing them to `Adobe Illustrator` to turn them into a gradient mesh. The procedure can be time consuming if I want to be very precise, and even there are only 4 vertices, I would have to manually adjusting their positions and all 8 handles, and then pick up the color from the original surface,  quite laborious. See my post [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42022/transforming-3rd-party-discrete-gradient-mesh-to-ais-smooth-gradient-mesh)

My question is: **Is it possible for pst-solides3d to implement an automation of the above procedure?**

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer to your question, so you may want to wait for other answers which your questions about `pst-solides3d`.

This answer is to build up the knowledge base and to address your last sentence in the linked question https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42022/transforming-3rd-party-discrete-gradient-mesh-to-ais-smooth-gradient-mesh, namely

> Alternatively, if there is a better way to do this, I would also like
>   to know it. Thank you.

From what I understand, you want

- a smooth gradient (=smooth shading)
- quadrilateral patches
- vector graphics

This specific problem can be solved by means of `pgfplots`. I have used a Möbius strip since I have neither your data files nor the parametrization of your surface:

1. bilinear patches. First-order resolution of the patch boundary, bilinear color interpolation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot3[
        surf, 
        samples=25, samples y=25,
        variable=r,   domain=-1:1,
        variable y=a, domain y=0:2*pi,
        trig format plots=rad,
        shader=faceted interp, 
        patch type=bilinear,
    ]
        ({cos(a) * (1+r/2 * cos(a/2))},
         {sin(a) * (1+r/2 * cos(a/2))},
         {r/2 * sin(a/2)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

2. bicubic patches. Third order resolution of the patch boundary (and less patches), bilinear color gradient:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot3[
        surf, 
        samples=10, samples y=10,
        variable=r,   domain=-1:1,
        variable y=a, domain y=0:2*pi,
        trig format plots=rad,
        shader=faceted interp, 
        patch type sampling, 
        patch type=bicubic,
    ]
        ({cos(a) * (1+r/2 * cos(a/2))},
         {sin(a) * (1+r/2 * cos(a/2))},
         {r/2 * sin(a/2)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both examples need the `patchplots` library, and both have a parameterized surface depending on `r` and `a`. The parameterization is from wikipedia. Note that `trig format plots=rad` switches the default config from degrees to radians.

Bicubic patches are quite difficult to generate: they have 16 points for each patch. The key `patch type sampling` simplifies this considerably -- if the input data is sampled from a function anyway. If you have table input, you will have to provide the patches on your own.

The colors are taken from a `colormap`: the smallest `z` coordinate is mapped to the first color of the `colormap`, the largest `z` coordinate is mapped to the last color of the `colormap`. Everything in-between is mapped linearly into the `colormap`. Further reading: keys `point meta` (choose which scalar value to use) and `colormap` (which `colormap`), also related are "Surface plots with explicit color".

Related question: [Creating Bezier surfaces using procedural graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99133/creating-bezier-surfaces-using-procedural-graphics)

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. Im wondering if I could use a different `colormap` (other than the height function)?

Comment: Sure. In this case, the simplest case would be some math expression using `point meta=<expression>`. The actual colors can be configured using `colormap` (details in the manual http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thank you. I have also another question, is it possible to remove the internal lines and only leave the boundary line of the surface? I fear not, since it involves Boolean operations.

Comment: This is impossible by means of `pgfplots`. You may consider using `mesh/interior colormap` which allows to choose a different colormap for the "other side" of the patches