# How to fill the intersection among four curves?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, intersections, clip

In my problem, all curves are plot from data instead of explicit function. And what I want to do is to fill those little curved rectangles with different colors. How could I do it?

[image]

Here is the tex for generate this figure.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{curvpts_1_u.txt}
X Y
-2.700000  -0.700000
-2.561250  -0.729000
-2.425000  -0.756000
-2.291250  -0.781000
-2.160000  -0.804000
-2.031250  -0.825000
-1.905000  -0.844000
-1.781250  -0.861000
-1.660000  -0.876000
-1.541250  -0.889000
-1.425000  -0.900000
-1.311250  -0.909000
-1.200000  -0.916000
-1.091250  -0.921000
-0.985000  -0.924000
-0.881250  -0.925000
-0.780000  -0.924000
-0.681250  -0.921000
-0.585000  -0.916000
-0.491250  -0.909000
-0.400000  -0.900000
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{curvpts_1_v.txt}
X Y
-2.700000  -0.700000
-2.650750  -0.639000
-2.603000  -0.576000
-2.556750  -0.511000
-2.512000  -0.444000
-2.468750  -0.375000
-2.427000  -0.304000
-2.386750  -0.231000
-2.348000  -0.156000
-2.310750  -0.079000
-2.275000  -0.000000
-2.240750  0.081000
-2.208000  0.164000
-2.176750  0.249000
-2.147000  0.336000
-2.118750  0.425000
-2.092000  0.516000
-2.066750  0.609000
-2.043000  0.704000
-2.020750  0.801000
-2.000000  0.900000
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{curvpts_2_u.txt}
X Y
-2.400000  -0.255556
-2.283500  -0.288972
-2.167333  -0.320333
-2.051500  -0.349639
-1.936000  -0.376889
-1.820833  -0.402083
-1.706000  -0.425222
-1.591500  -0.446306
-1.477333  -0.465333
-1.363500  -0.482306
-1.250000  -0.497222
-1.136833  -0.510083
-1.024000  -0.520889
-0.911500  -0.529639
-0.799333  -0.536333
-0.687500  -0.540972
-0.576000  -0.543556
-0.464833  -0.544083
-0.354000  -0.542556
-0.243500  -0.538972
-0.133333  -0.533333
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{curvpts_2_v.txt}
X Y
-1.822222  -0.855556
-1.794278  -0.798972
-1.766000  -0.740333
-1.737389  -0.679639
-1.708444  -0.616889
-1.679167  -0.552083
-1.649556  -0.485222
-1.619611  -0.416306
-1.589333  -0.345333
-1.558722  -0.272306
-1.527778  -0.197222
-1.496500  -0.120083
-1.464889  -0.040889
-1.432944  0.040361
-1.400667  0.123667
-1.368056  0.209028
-1.335111  0.296444
-1.301833  0.385917
-1.268222  0.477444
-1.234278  0.571028
-1.200000  0.666667
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{curvpts_3_u.txt}
X Y
-2.166667  0.277778
-2.053583  0.243778
-1.941000  0.210667
-1.828917  0.178444
-1.717333  0.147111
-1.606250  0.116667
-1.495667  0.087111
-1.385583  0.058444
-1.276000  0.030667
-1.166917  0.003778
-1.058333  -0.022222
-0.950250  -0.047333
-0.842667  -0.071556
-0.735583  -0.094889
-0.629000  -0.117333
-0.522917  -0.138889
-0.417333  -0.159556
-0.312250  -0.179333
-0.207667  -0.198222
-0.103583  -0.216222
-0.000000  -0.233333
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{curvpts_3_v.txt}
X Y
-1.055556  -0.922222
-1.027861  -0.866222
-1.000333  -0.809333
-0.972972  -0.751556
-0.945778  -0.692889
-0.918750  -0.633333
-0.891889  -0.572889
-0.865194  -0.511556
-0.838667  -0.449333
-0.812306  -0.386222
-0.786111  -0.322222
-0.760083  -0.257333
-0.734222  -0.191556
-0.708528  -0.124889
-0.683000  -0.057333
-0.657639  0.011111
-0.632444  0.080444
-0.607417  0.150667
-0.582556  0.221778
-0.557861  0.293778
-0.533333  0.366667
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{curvpts_4_u.txt}
X Y
-2.000000  0.900000
-1.871500  0.869250
-1.746000  0.837000
-1.623500  0.803250
-1.504000  0.768000
-1.387500  0.731250
-1.274000  0.693000
-1.163500  0.653250
-1.056000  0.612000
-0.951500  0.569250
-0.850000  0.525000
-0.751500  0.479250
-0.656000  0.432000
-0.563500  0.383250
-0.474000  0.333000
-0.387500  0.281250
-0.304000  0.228000
-0.223500  0.173250
-0.146000  0.117000
-0.071500  0.059250
0.000000  0.000000
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{curvpts_4_v.txt}
X Y
-0.400000  -0.900000
-0.351500  -0.840750
-0.306000  -0.783000
-0.263500  -0.726750
-0.224000  -0.672000
-0.187500  -0.618750
-0.154000  -0.567000
-0.123500  -0.516750
-0.096000  -0.468000
-0.071500  -0.420750
-0.050000  -0.375000
-0.031500  -0.330750
-0.016000  -0.288000
-0.003500  -0.246750
0.006000  -0.207000
0.012500  -0.168750
0.016000  -0.132000
0.016500  -0.096750
0.014000  -0.063000
0.008500  -0.030750
0.000000  0.000000    
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 5]
 \begin{axis}[hide axis, axis equal, view={0}{90}]

    \foreach \f in {1,2,...,4}{\addplot[mark=none, color = blue,thick, smooth, line cap=round] table [] {curvpts_\f_u.txt};}
    \foreach \f in {1,2,...,4}{\addplot[mark=none, color = blue, thick, smooth, line cap=round] table [] {curvpts_\f_v.txt};}

 \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I modified it , thx.

Comment: The image looks as if you want to simulate some sort of `patch` plot: a `patch` plot consists of a sequence of (curved) rectangles and color data at each vertex. The result is that each rectangle has its own color, perhaps even a shading. If you have something like this in mind, you may be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99133/creating-bezier-surfaces-using-procedural-graphics/102585#102585

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give you an example which will allow you to fill any of the "rectangles". The strategy is to name the paths and then combine different intersection segments to new paths, which can ultimately be filled.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{curvpts_1_u.txt}
X Y
-2.700000  -0.700000
-2.561250  -0.729000
-2.425000  -0.756000
-2.291250  -0.781000
-2.160000  -0.804000
-2.031250  -0.825000
-1.905000  -0.844000
-1.781250  -0.861000
-1.660000  -0.876000
-1.541250  -0.889000
-1.425000  -0.900000
-1.311250  -0.909000
-1.200000  -0.916000
-1.091250  -0.921000
-0.985000  -0.924000
-0.881250  -0.925000
-0.780000  -0.924000
-0.681250  -0.921000
-0.585000  -0.916000
-0.491250  -0.909000
-0.400000  -0.900000
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{curvpts_1_v.txt}
X Y
-2.700000  -0.700000
-2.650750  -0.639000
-2.603000  -0.576000
-2.556750  -0.511000
-2.512000  -0.444000
-2.468750  -0.375000
-2.427000  -0.304000
-2.386750  -0.231000
-2.348000  -0.156000
-2.310750  -0.079000
-2.275000  -0.000000
-2.240750  0.081000
-2.208000  0.164000
-2.176750  0.249000
-2.147000  0.336000
-2.118750  0.425000
-2.092000  0.516000
-2.066750  0.609000
-2.043000  0.704000
-2.020750  0.801000
-2.000000  0.900000
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{curvpts_2_u.txt}
X Y
-2.400000  -0.255556
-2.283500  -0.288972
-2.167333  -0.320333
-2.051500  -0.349639
-1.936000  -0.376889
-1.820833  -0.402083
-1.706000  -0.425222
-1.591500  -0.446306
-1.477333  -0.465333
-1.363500  -0.482306
-1.250000  -0.497222
-1.136833  -0.510083
-1.024000  -0.520889
-0.911500  -0.529639
-0.799333  -0.536333
-0.687500  -0.540972
-0.576000  -0.543556
-0.464833  -0.544083
-0.354000  -0.542556
-0.243500  -0.538972
-0.133333  -0.533333
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{curvpts_2_v.txt}
X Y
-1.822222  -0.855556
-1.794278  -0.798972
-1.766000  -0.740333
-1.737389  -0.679639
-1.708444  -0.616889
-1.679167  -0.552083
-1.649556  -0.485222
-1.619611  -0.416306
-1.589333  -0.345333
-1.558722  -0.272306
-1.527778  -0.197222
-1.496500  -0.120083
-1.464889  -0.040889
-1.432944  0.040361
-1.400667  0.123667
-1.368056  0.209028
-1.335111  0.296444
-1.301833  0.385917
-1.268222  0.477444
-1.234278  0.571028
-1.200000  0.666667
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{curvpts_3_u.txt}
X Y
-2.166667  0.277778
-2.053583  0.243778
-1.941000  0.210667
-1.828917  0.178444
-1.717333  0.147111
-1.606250  0.116667
-1.495667  0.087111
-1.385583  0.058444
-1.276000  0.030667
-1.166917  0.003778
-1.058333  -0.022222
-0.950250  -0.047333
-0.842667  -0.071556
-0.735583  -0.094889
-0.629000  -0.117333
-0.522917  -0.138889
-0.417333  -0.159556
-0.312250  -0.179333
-0.207667  -0.198222
-0.103583  -0.216222
-0.000000  -0.233333
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{curvpts_3_v.txt}
X Y
-1.055556  -0.922222
-1.027861  -0.866222
-1.000333  -0.809333
-0.972972  -0.751556
-0.945778  -0.692889
-0.918750  -0.633333
-0.891889  -0.572889
-0.865194  -0.511556
-0.838667  -0.449333
-0.812306  -0.386222
-0.786111  -0.322222
-0.760083  -0.257333
-0.734222  -0.191556
-0.708528  -0.124889
-0.683000  -0.057333
-0.657639  0.011111
-0.632444  0.080444
-0.607417  0.150667
-0.582556  0.221778
-0.557861  0.293778
-0.533333  0.366667
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{curvpts_4_u.txt}
X Y
-2.000000  0.900000
-1.871500  0.869250
-1.746000  0.837000
-1.623500  0.803250
-1.504000  0.768000
-1.387500  0.731250
-1.274000  0.693000
-1.163500  0.653250
-1.056000  0.612000
-0.951500  0.569250
-0.850000  0.525000
-0.751500  0.479250
-0.656000  0.432000
-0.563500  0.383250
-0.474000  0.333000
-0.387500  0.281250
-0.304000  0.228000
-0.223500  0.173250
-0.146000  0.117000
-0.071500  0.059250
0.000000  0.000000
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{curvpts_4_v.txt}
X Y
-0.400000  -0.900000
-0.351500  -0.840750
-0.306000  -0.783000
-0.263500  -0.726750
-0.224000  -0.672000
-0.187500  -0.618750
-0.154000  -0.567000
-0.123500  -0.516750
-0.096000  -0.468000
-0.071500  -0.420750
-0.050000  -0.375000
-0.031500  -0.330750
-0.016000  -0.288000
-0.003500  -0.246750
0.006000  -0.207000
0.012500  -0.168750
0.016000  -0.132000
0.016500  -0.096750
0.014000  -0.063000
0.008500  -0.030750
0.000000  0.000000    
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} %<- added


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 5]
 \begin{axis}[hide axis, axis equal, view={0}{90}]

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,...,4}{
    \addplot[name path=horizontal#1,mark=none, color = blue,thick, smooth, line cap=round]
    table [] {curvpts_#1_u.txt};
    \addplot[name path=vertical#1,mark=none, color = blue, thick, smooth, line cap=round]
    table [] {curvpts_#1_v.txt};
    }
      \path [%draw,line width=3,purple,
    name path=1and1,
    intersection segments={
        of=horizontal1 and vertical1,
        sequence={B1[reverse]-- A1}
    }];
      \path [%draw,line width=3,red,
    name path=2and2left,
    intersection segments={
        of=horizontal2 and vertical2,
        sequence={B0-- A0[reverse]}
    }];
    \path [%draw,line width=3,purple,
    name path=1and1left,
    intersection segments={
        of=1and1 and 2and2left,
        sequence={A1}
    }];
    \addplot [orange] fill between [of=1and1left and 2and2left];
 \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you plan to fill most of the segments, you may be better off if you define some segments that "meander" through the figure and then use the split syntax that is explained on page 434 of the pgfplots manual.

Comment: Thanks, it looks great! But when I implement your code, "\addplot [orange] fill between [of=1and1left and 2and2left];" gives a blank pdf file.

Comment: @DiMiao The only explanation I could come up with is that you're using an older version of pgfplots. Does it run if you set `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}`?

Comment: You are right. It works now, thx.