# Drawing a shaded hemisphere using tikz?

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I want to draw a shaded hemisphere using tikz. The final result should look like this (the lower part of the sphere should be removed):

[image]

Until now I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}  %generates a tightly fitting border around the work
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}

%define polar coordinates for some vector
%TODO: look into using 3d spherical coordinate system
\pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{1.0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{0}

%start tikz picture, and use the tdplot_main_coords style to implement the display 
%coordinate transformation provided by 3dplot
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]

--

%draw the main coordinate system axes
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (-1,0,0) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$y$};

\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}

%draw some dashed arcs, demonstrating direct arc drawing
\draw[dashed,tdplot_rotated_coords] (\radius,0,0) arc (0:90:\radius);

%\draw[dashed,tdplot_rotated_coords] (\radius,0,0) arc (0:90:\radius);

\draw[dashed] (\radius,0,0) arc (0:360:\radius);
\shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.20] (0,0) circle (1cm);
% (-z x y)
\draw (0, 1, 0) node [circle, fill=blue, inner sep=.02cm] () {};
\draw (0, 0, 1) node [circle, fill=green, inner sep=.02cm] () {};
\draw (-1, 0, 0) node [circle, fill=red, inner sep=.02cm] () {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is there any possibility to get rid of the lower part of the sphere?

Comment: [Something like this?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VBFZr.png) I would have posted an answer already but there is a small imperfection in the lower left side. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: @Alenanno yes - looks very good.I hope you can fix the small problem on the lower left side.

Comment: See the answer. I realize I have been looking for the harder solution when there was a simpler one in front of me all the time.

Comment: You might want to consider [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) if you need to add complexity and real 3D (see [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39577/what-are-the-relative-strengths-of-tikz-and-asymptote)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was so focused  into using intersection segments that I didn't think of a simpler solution. Simply draw the lower arc (middle section) and then the dome and shade the path.

Basically this is what the path looks like:

[image: figure 1]

### Output

[image: figure 2]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}

%define polar coordinates for some vector
%TODO: look into using 3d spherical coordinate system
\pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{0}

%start tikz picture, and use the tdplot_main_coords style to implement the display 
%coordinate transformation provided by 3dplot
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]
%draw the main coordinate system axes
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (-1,0,0) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$y$};

\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}

%draw some dashed arcs, demonstrating direct arc drawing
\draw[dashed,tdplot_rotated_coords] (\radius,0,0) arc (0:90:\radius);

\draw[dashed] (\radius,0,0) arc (0:360:\radius);
\shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.2] (1cm,0) arc (0:-180:1cm and 5mm) arc (180:0:1cm and 1cm);
% (-z x y)
\draw (0, 1, 0) node [circle, fill=blue, inner sep=.02cm] () {};
\draw (0, 0, 1) node [circle, fill=green, inner sep=.02cm] () {};
\draw (-1, 0, 0) node [circle, fill=red, inner sep=.02cm] () {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```