# Asymptote 3d: Remove the flicker from the dots of a dice to play?

Tags: 3d, asymptote, fill, clip

I coded my first figure with Asymptote in 3d which is a dice to play with faces numbered by one to six points representing numbers 1 to 6 in a classic way. This dice can be manipulated with the mouse.

The problem is that the discs representing the dots sparkle when you manipulate the dice.

When I comment the draw statement (line 25) `draw(scale3(84a)*unitcube, surfacepen=white);` then the discs do not flicker at all, but suddenly the dice becomes transparent. I conclude that the problem comes from the fact that the color blue of the discs is overprinting on the white color of the faces. A solution would therefore be to color the faces in two steps as can be done with Tikz:

- Faces without discs in blank
- Single discs in blue

But the `clip`, `fill`, `unfill`, `filldraw` commands do not work with the 3d `surface()` function.

How can we color the faces of the dice without flickering?

The Asymptote file `.asy` is the following, (the code is not optimized so as to be readable):

```
import three;
currentprojection =orthographic((5,2,3));
currentlight=nolight; 
settings.tex="latex"; // Moteur LaTeX utilisé pour la compilation (latex, pdflatex, ...)
settings.outformat="pdf"; // Format de sortie ; eps par défaut
settings.prc=true; // Format PRC de la figure ; vrai par défaut
settings.render=-1; // Rendu des figures ; -1 par défaut
size(6cm,0);
real a = 0.05;
path    carre = box ((0,0),(84a,84a)),
        disque = scale(9a)*unitcircle,
        patron1[] = shift(42a,42a)*disque,
        patron2[] = shift(14a,70a)*disque^^shift(70a,14a)*disque,
        patron3[] = shift(14a,70a)*disque^^shift(70a,14a)*disque^^shift(42a,42a)*disque,
        patron4[] = shift(14a,14a)*disque^^shift(14a,70a)*disque^^shift(70a,14a)*disque^^shift(70a,70a)*disque,
        patron5[] = shift(14a,14a)*disque^^shift(14a,70a)*disque^^shift(70a,14a)*disque^^shift(70a,70a)*disque^^shift(42a,42a)*disque,
        patron6[] = shift(14a,14a)*disque^^shift(14a,70a)*disque^^shift(70a,14a)*disque^^shift(70a,70a)*disque^^shift(42a,70a)*disque^^shift(42a,14a)*disque;
transform3 tX=shift(84a*X), tY=shift(84a*Y), tZ=shift(84a*Z);       
path3   facegauche[] =path3(patron6,ZXplane),
        facedroite[] =path3(patron1,ZXplane),
        faceavant[] =path3(patron2,YZplane),
        facearriere[] =path3(patron5,YZplane),  
        facehaut[] =path3(patron4,XYplane),     
        facebas[] =path3(patron3,XYplane);      
draw(scale3(84a)*unitcube, surfacepen=white);
draw(box(O, 84a*(X+Y+Z)), gray);
draw(surface(facegauche),blue);
draw(surface(tY*facedroite),blue);
draw(surface(tZ*facehaut),blue);
draw(surface(facebas),blue);
draw(surface(facearriere),blue);
draw(surface(tX*faceavant),blue);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a french answer on a french forum, please find an approximate english answer.
In fact the discs are on/in the faces of the cube but it is not possible to know what is the relative position of the discs with respect to the faces.
Depending on the numerical approximation, the discs are above/below of the faces and numerical artefacts create flickers.

Solution 1) : shift each disc in the right direction, which is proposed here

```
import three;
currentprojection =orthographic((5,2,3));
currentlight=nolight;
settings.tex="latex"; // Moteur LaTeX utilisé pour la compilation (latex, pdflatex, ...)
settings.outformat="pdf"; // Format de sortie ; eps par défaut
settings.prc=true; // Format PRC de la figure ; vrai par défaut
settings.render=-1; // Rendu des figures ; -1 par défaut
size(6cm,0);
real a = 0.05;
path    carre = box ((0,0),(84a,84a)),
      disque = scale(9a)*unitcircle,
      patron1[] = shift(42a,42a)*disque,
      patron2[] = shift(14a,70a)*disque^^shift(70a,14a)*disque,
      patron3[] = shift(14a,70a)*disque^^shift(70a,14a)*disque^^shift(42a,42a)*disque,
      patron4[] = shift(14a,14a)*disque^^shift(14a,70a)*disque^^shift(70a,14a)*disque^^shift(70a,70a)*disque,
      patron5[] = shift(14a,14a)*disque^^shift(14a,70a)*disque^^shift(70a,14a)*disque^^shift(70a,70a)*disque^^shift(42a,42a)*disque,
      patron6[] = shift(14a,14a)*disque^^shift(14a,70a)*disque^^shift(70a,14a)*disque^^shift(70a,70a)*disque^^shift(42a,70a)*disque^^shift(42a,14a)*disque;
transform3 tX=shift((84a+00.1)*X), tY=shift((84a+.001)*Y), tZ=shift((84a+0.01)*Z);      
path3    facegauche[] =shift(0,-0.001,0)*path3(patron6,ZXplane),
      facedroite[] =path3(patron1,ZXplane),
      faceavant[] =path3(patron2,YZplane),
      facearriere[] =shift(-0.001,0,0)*path3(patron5,YZplane),   
      facehaut[] =path3(patron4,XYplane),      
      facebas[] =shift(0,0,-0.001)*path3(patron3,XYplane);      
draw(scale3(84a)*unitcube, surfacepen=white);
draw(box(O, 84a*(X+Y+Z)), gray);
draw(surface(facegauche),blue);
draw(surface(tY*facedroite),blue);
draw(surface(tZ*facehaut),blue);
draw(surface(facebas),blue);
draw(surface(facearriere),blue);
draw(surface(tX*faceavant),blue);
```

Solution 2) : create the real surface of the dice faces.
Update: please find the 2nd solution. Indeed `bezulate` can transform 2D path into a 3D. According to the documention,

> Planar Bezier surfaces patches are constructed using Orest Shardt’s bezulate routine, which decomposes (possibly nonsimply connected) regions bounded (according to the zerowinding fill rule) by simple cyclic paths (intersecting only at the endpoints) into subregions bounded by cyclic paths of length 4 or less.

To create hole it is necessary to use `reverse` (running backwards along the path) : for example `bezulate(unitsquate^^reverse(scale(.3)*unitcircle))`. 
Then `surface(bezulate(unitsquate^^reverse(scale(.3)*unitcircle)))` creates the surface of a unitsquare with small hole.
The code for the complete dice.

```
import three;
currentprojection =orthographic((5,2,3));
currentlight=nolight;
settings.tex="latex"; // Moteur LaTeX utilisé pour la compilation (latex, pdflatex, ...)
//settings.outformat="pdf"; // Format de sortie ; eps par défaut
settings.prc=true; // Format PRC de la figure ; vrai par défaut
settings.render=-1; // Rendu des figures ; -1 par défaut
size(6cm,0);
real a = 0.05;
path    carre = box ((0,0),(84a,84a)),
      // reverse est capital pour créer les trous avec bezulate
      // c'est la règle : unitsquare et disque ne seront pas dans le
      // même sens, donc bezulate comprend que c'est un trou
      disque = scale(9a)*reverse(unitcircle),  

      patron1[] = shift(42a,42a)*disque,
      patron2[] = shift(14a,70a)*disque^^shift(70a,14a)*disque,
      patron3[] = shift(14a,70a)*disque^^shift(70a,14a)*disque^^shift(42a,42a)*disque,
      patron4[] = shift(14a,14a)*disque^^shift(14a,70a)*disque^^shift(70a,14a)*disque^^shift(70a,70a)*disque,
      patron5[] = shift(14a,14a)*disque^^shift(14a,70a)*disque^^shift(70a,14a)*disque^^shift(70a,70a)*disque^^shift(42a,42a)*disque,
      patron6[]=  shift(14a,14a)*disque^^shift(14a,70a)*disque^^shift(70a,14a)*disque^^shift(70a,70a)*disque^^shift(42a,70a)*disque^^shift(42a,14a)*disque;
transform3 tX=shift((84a)*X), tY=shift((84a)*Y), tZ=shift((84a)*Z);      
path3    facegauche[] =path3(patron6,ZXplane),
      facedroite[] =path3(patron1,ZXplane),
      faceavant[] =path3(patron2,YZplane),
      facearriere[] =path3(patron5,YZplane),   
      facehaut[] =path3(patron4,XYplane),      
      facebas[] =path3(patron3,XYplane);      

 //   draw(scale3(84a)*unitcube, surfacepen=white);
draw(box(O, 84a*(X+Y+Z)), gray);
draw(surface(facegauche),blue);
draw(surface(tY*facedroite),blue);
draw(surface(tZ*facehaut),blue);
draw(surface(facebas),blue);
draw(surface(facearriere),blue);
draw(surface(tX*faceavant),blue);
 // les faces trouées
path[] gp6=bezulate(scale(84a)*unitsquare^^patron6);
path[] gp5=bezulate(scale(84a)*unitsquare^^patron5);
path[] gp4=bezulate(scale(84a)*unitsquare^^patron4);
path[] gp3=bezulate(scale(84a)*unitsquare^^patron3);
path[] gp2=bezulate(scale(84a)*unitsquare^^patron2);
path[] gp1=bezulate(scale(84a)*unitsquare^^patron1);
surface s1=shift((0,84a,84a))*rotate(90,Y)*rotate(90,X)*surface(gp1);
surface s2=shift(84a,0,0)*rotate(-90,Y)*surface(gp2);
surface s3=surface(gp3);
surface s4=shift((0,0,84a))*surface(gp4);
surface s5=shift((0,0,84a))*rotate(90,Y)*surface(gp5);
surface s6=shift((0,0,84a))*rotate(90,Y)*rotate(90,X)*surface(gp6);
draw(s6,red);
draw(s5,red);
draw(s4,red);
draw(s3,red);
draw(s2,red);
draw(s1,red);
```

and the result

[image]

O.G.

Comment: @ O;G thanks it work very well. Thanks too for the french answer here : [mathematex](http://forum.mathematex.net/asymptote-f34/supprimer-le-scintillement-d-un-de-a-jouer-en-3d-t16837.html)