# asymptote versus tikz and usage in documents created with Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote

Is it better to use tikz or asymptote
Any comparison available 
Can asymptote code be added directly to a Latex book/letter/article along with tikz

Comment: See this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39577/28557

Comment: Asymptote allows you to build 3D figures and create pdf files in PRC format, which Tikz does not allow. This format allows you to manipulate 3D objects with the mouse by rotating them so that they are visible on all sides. An example is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/379969/138900

Comment: Note that the best answer to that question is not IMNSHO the accepted one. Note https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224727/ in particular.

Comment: Export to
[3D vector WebGL graphics](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/3Dwebgl/) 
within HTML files
was added to Asymptote recently.