# Handy TikZ's `node` version in Asymptote?

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote

I am interested in a variation of the classical SIR model in epidemics.
The illustration with TikZ is simple with handy `node`s.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{1.5}
\path[nodes={draw,circle,minimum size=8mm,fill=yellow,draw=blue}]
(210:\a) node (S) {$S$}
(-30:\a) node (I) {$I$}
(90:\a)  node (R) {$R$}
;
\draw[->] (S)--(I);
\draw[->] (I)--(R);
\draw[->] (R)--(S);
\draw[->] (R.0) to[out=0,in=60] (I.60);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For me it's quite complicated when using Asymptote to illustrate the above simple diagram. Asymptote is powerful, and I suppose it should cover graceful feature of TikZ's `node` (`inner sep`, `minimum width`, `shape=circle`, `shape=ellipse`, `anchor`, `.center`, `S.30`, etc). The following is what I have tried so far.

First try fails in controlling arrow tips, circle shape, and size of labels.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1.5cm);
path R=dir(90), S=dir(210), I=dir(-30);

Label LS = Label("$S$", FillDraw(yellow,blue));
Label LI = Label("$I$", FillDraw(yellow,blue));
Label LR = Label("$R$", FillDraw(yellow,blue));

draw(S--I--R--cycle);
path pRI=arc((0,0),1,90,-30);
draw(pRI);
label(LS,S);
label(LI,I);
label(LR,R);
```

Second try can make circle shape, arrow tips, but fails in controlling incline connector, size of labels, filling and drawing shape with color (yellow, blue).

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1.5cm);
import flowchart;
pair R=dir(90), S=dir(210), I=dir(-30);
block blockS=circle("S",S);
block blockI=circle("I",I);
block blockR=circle("R",R);

draw(blockS,blue);
draw(blockI);
draw(blockR);

add(new void(picture pic, transform t) {
    blockconnector operator --=blockconnector(pic,t);
    blockS--Arrow(TeXHead)--blockI;
   blockI--Arrow(TeXHead)--blockR;
  });
```

In summary, I have 2 questions in drawing with Asymptote.

**Question 1:** How to draw arrows from S to I, I to R, R to I such that arrow tips touch the blue boundaries?

**Question 2:** How to make circular/elliptic shapes around label S,I,R ?

**Update 24 Dec 2020** It seems that Asymptote's `object`s do the job. In my third try, arrow tips touched the blue boundaries, but all shapes are ellipses, not circles (see `I`), and I have to specify boundary point by hand (see `point(LI,dir(120),t)`).
The code is extracted from [Asymptote's gallery](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/advection.asy), so my questions is more reasonable.

[image]

```
unitsize(1.5cm);
pair R=dir(90), S=dir(210), I=dir(-30);
real margin=3mm;

object LS=draw("$S$",ellipse,S,margin,FillDraw(yellow,blue));
object LI=draw("$I$",ellipse,I,margin,FillDraw(yellow,blue));
object LR=draw("$R$",ellipse,R,margin,FillDraw(yellow,blue));

add(new void(frame f, transform t) {
    picture pic;
    draw(pic,point(LS,E,t)--point(LI,W,t),red,Arrow(TeXHead),PenMargin);
    draw(pic,point(LI,dir(120),t)--point(LR,dir(-60),t),red,Arrow(TeXHead),PenMargin);
    draw(pic,point(LR,dir(240),t)--point(LS,dir(60),t),red,Arrow(TeXHead),PenMargin);
    pair R1=point(LR,NE,t), I1=point(LI,NE,t);
    path pRI=R1 .. controls R1+30*dir(45) and I1+40*dir(35).. I1; 
   draw(pic,pRI,red,Arrow(TeXHead),PenMargin);

    add(f,pic.fit());
  });

shipout(bbox(5mm));
```

Comment: Although I'm normally all in favor of using Asymptote, for diagrams with arrows between text TikZ is far superior. Do you have a really good reason to use Asymptote instead for this? (E.g., you want to incorporate this diagram into another, more complex diagram?)

Comment: I've had very good luck with the package here: https://github.com/taoari/asy-graphtheory/blob/master/Usage.md (Although I'll note that it is not official, and the documentation is not the best, and I know of a bug or two that the author has not fixed.)

Comment: @CharlesStaats While we are thinking more about a really good reason to use Asymptote to draw diagrams with arrows, I have just added an update code. It seems that Asymptote's `object`s is similar to TikZ's `node`'s.

Comment: @CharlesStaats: I agree that for 2D diagrams with arrows, TikZ is a good choice. The reason for my question is from an advertising of Asymptote: "Why was the name Asymptote chosen? Well, it isn't the perfect graphics package, but we do think it is getting there asymptotically..." Moreover, 3D node seems promissing concept. https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/FAQ/section1.html#whyasy

Answer (score 2):

This is long comment, and still not a concise answer.

I found the [2009 link](https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-doc/commit/6bdfa55a643538ac36df231f76f64435a0879df8?fbclid=IwAR2fzDFy0ZquhzjhFQGEmXcuDGANqUVghDVGLqVjt8v8yB3ih7sC68B5CWg) that use `import node;` In that `node.asy`, the syntax is still somehow not so handy in my subjective opinion. Also see [Jim Heffron's answer](https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftex.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F173001%2Fhow-to-create-a-graph-of-our-own-in-latex%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR1ZIi6nEzX1VpNzWIdD-tKLvCJa-LnNIDjKWMhM3HKaNfW-PPOm4-DSIXs&h=AT1FsilBouIXrLXe75BK2Gkhp3rS9gbx5Dw7Zp-d8w-Nb8Ob92NrGR2Moq8EJMEiVIhsFcfhtbirdNbj1ioEnEj8Ek7t2j0WFFJnDnZfnxbSsrAeStcdVuulhKDLIXfA4w&__tn__=R%5D-R&c%5B0%5D=AT1kRbdogJSSnkIFiTVBbDHk_d7zPYUs6QTzC1r7dPPnaerf-fFj_w5BM0xsYWg2CkmmxdKUfpUBvvoU06hKokVubx8yTzZ16zrSBD23NXl3-WmoXWAiknKD1Kruy87JoAmeRn23PFVK_WXFDElx8d5goGOLmoQIuvM7uGwBgTdHB3Cio-FeZYV2KBlGomhYhpJhuOkOMUh0_VOufg) from 2014.

From the above link, I make my 4th try. First recall that the syntax of `object` from `plain_boxes.asy`

```
object draw(picture pic=currentpicture, Label L, envelope e,
            pair position=(0,0), real xmargin=0, real ymargin=xmargin,
            pen p=currentpen, filltype filltype=NoFill);
```

There are shapes of `box` (rectangle), `ellipse`, `roundbox`, but **there is no `circle` shape**. We can control `Draw`, `Fill`, `xmargin` and `ymargin` (like TikZ's `inner sep`); we can get any point in the boundary (TikZ's `anchor`s) of the defined `object`.

[image]

```
object
cat = draw("cat", box, (0,0), Draw),
dog = draw("dog", ellipse, (2cm,0), Fill(olive)),
elephant = draw("elephant", roundbox, (0,-2cm),xmargin=2mm,FillDraw(lightblue, darkblue));

pair C=point(cat,E),Ct=point(cat,S);
pair D=point(dog,-90), Dt=point(dog,SW);
pair E=point(elephant,N), Et=point(elephant,NNE);
draw(C--D,red,Arrow(TeXHead));
draw(Et--Dt,red,Arrow(TeXHead));
draw(E--Ct,red,Arrow(TeXHead));
```

Then I come to this, simple code with quite good look, except all shapes are ellipses, not circles.

[image]

```
object
S=draw("S",ellipse,(0,0),xmargin=3mm,FillDraw(yellow,blue)),
I=draw("I",ellipse,(4cm,0),xmargin=3mm,FillDraw(yellow,blue)),
R=draw("R",ellipse,(2cm,3cm),xmargin=3mm,FillDraw(yellow,blue));

pair 
S1=point(S,E), I1=point(I,W),
I2=point(I,dir(120)), R1=point(R,dir(-60)),
R2=point(R,dir(-120)), S2=point(S,dir(60)),
R3=point(R,dir(-20)), I3=point(I,dir(70))
;

DefaultHead=TeXHead;
draw(S1--I1,red,Arrow());
draw(I2--R1,red,Arrow());
draw(R2--S2,red,Arrow());
draw(R3 .. controls  R3+1cm*dir(0) and  I3+1cm*dir(70) .. I3,red,Arrow());
```

**Update:** by putting the `circle` shape (@Nguyen Van Chi mimicked form the `roundbox` shape in `plain_boxes.asy`), it works well (change `ellipse` to `circle`) ^^ I think now defining a new shape (trapezium, parallellogram, star, ...) is an comfortable task in Asymptote (even more comfortable than defining a new shape in TikZ's `node`)

[image]

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// code for the `circle` shape from Nguyen Van Chi, 
// inspired by the `roundbox` shape (see `plain_boxes.asy`)
path circle(frame dest, frame src=dest, real xmargin=0, real ymargin=xmargin,
            pen p=currentpen, filltype filltype=NoFill, bool above=true)
{ 
pair m=min(src);
pair M=max(src);
pair bound=M-m;
real a=bound.x+2*xmargin;
real b=bound.y+2*ymargin;
path g=shift(m-(xmargin,ymargin))*(circle((a/2,b/2),max(a,b)/2));
frame F;
 if(above == false) {
    filltype.fill(F,g,p);
    prepend(dest,F);
  } else filltype.fill(dest,g,p);
return g;
}

path circle(frame f, Label L, real xmargin=0, real ymargin=xmargin,
            pen p=currentpen, filltype filltype=NoFill, bool above=true)
{
add(f,L);
return circle(f,xmargin,ymargin,p,filltype,above);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

object
S=draw("S",circle,(0,0),xmargin=3mm,FillDraw(yellow,blue)),
I=draw("I",circle,(4cm,0),xmargin=3mm,FillDraw(yellow,blue)),
R=draw("R",circle,(2cm,3cm),xmargin=3mm,FillDraw(yellow,blue));

pair 
S1=point(S,E), I1=point(I,W),
I2=point(I,dir(120)), R1=point(R,dir(-60)),
R2=point(R,dir(-120)), S2=point(S,dir(60)),
R3=point(R,dir(-20)), I3=point(I,dir(70))
;

DefaultHead=TeXHead;
draw(S1--I1,red,Arrow());
draw(I2--R1,red,Arrow());
draw(R2--S2,red,Arrow());
draw(R3 .. controls  R3+1cm*dir(0) and  I3+1cm*dir(70) .. I3,red,Arrow());

add(bbox(5mm));
```

Answer (score 2):

**Diagrams with arrows can be drawn with plain Asymptote, ALMOST as simple as with plain TikZ**.

I am quite comfortable with this solution, but still open for better ones. My way is using plain Asymptote: no other command/module needed.

Note that a circle is an ellipse with equal sizes. By combining `object` and `label`, we can get the `circle` shape, hence making uniform size for all circle shapes (similar to `minimum width` of TikZ's node).

[image]

```
object
S=draw("",ellipse,(0,0),xmargin=3mm,FillDraw(yellow,blue)),
I=draw("",ellipse,(4cm,0),xmargin=3mm,FillDraw(yellow,blue)),
R=draw("",ellipse,(2cm,3cm),xmargin=3mm,FillDraw(yellow,blue));
label("S",(0,0));
label("I",(4cm,0));
label("R",(2cm,3cm));
pair
S1=point(S,E), I1=point(I,W),
I2=point(I,dir(120)), R1=point(R,dir(-60)),
R2=point(R,dir(-120)), S2=point(S,dir(60)),
R3=point(R,dir(-20)), I3=point(I,dir(70))
;
DefaultHead=TeXHead;
draw(S1--I1,red,Arrow());
draw(I2--R1,red,Arrow());
draw(R2--S2,red,Arrow());
draw(R3 .. controls R3+1cm*dir(0) and I3+1cm*dir(70) .. I3,red,Arrow());
```

So far, usual TikZ's `node` involving options (`inner sep`, `inner xsep`, `inner ysep`, `fill`, `draw`, `minimum size`, `shorten >`, `anchor` of border shape, `shorten <`, `circle`, `ellipse`, `rectangle`, `loop`, `scale`, `sloped`, `rotate`, `text color`) are easily translated to Asymptote. I am not going to test some other features (`anchor`s of text, aligning nodes, ...).

[image]

```
// Diagrams with arrows can be drawn with plain Asymptote
object
S=draw("",ellipse,(0,0),xmargin=6mm,FillDraw(yellow,blue)),
I=draw("",ellipse,(4cm,0),xmargin=3mm,FillDraw(yellow,blue)),
R=draw("",ellipse,(2cm,3cm),xmargin=3mm,FillDraw(yellow,blue));
label(scale(3)*"S",(0,0));
label(scale(.5)*"i",(4cm,0));
label("R",(2cm,3cm));

pair
S1=point(S,E), I1=point(I,W),
I2=point(I,dir(120)), R1=point(R,dir(-60)),
R2=point(R,dir(-120)), S2=point(S,dir(60)),
R3=point(R,dir(-20)), I3=point(I,dir(70)),
I4=point(I,dir(-45))
;

DefaultHead=TeXHead;
draw("$\alpha$",S1--I1,purple,Arrow(),margin=TrueMargin(.5mm, 2mm));
draw(Label("$\beta$",align=SW),I2--R1,red,Arrow(),margin=TrueMargin(1mm));
draw(Label("gamma",Rotate(R2-S2)),R2--S2,red,Arrow());
draw("$\delta$",R3{0} .. {-60}I3,red,Arrow(),margin=TrueMargin(2mm));
draw(Label("go to Heaven",align=plain.S,EndPoint),I4--I4+1cm*dir(-45),cyan,Arrow);

add(bbox(5mm));
```

Sometimes TikZ makes LaTeX more beautiful with tables as tikzpicture via `matrix of nodes`, `matrix of math nodes`. In my current opinion, those options should not be expected in Asymptote due to standalone nature of each figure, and Asymptote's strength is real 3D. I am not considering TikZ as a standard of drawing, but it is a starting viewpoint when caring what Asymptote can help me/us expressing ideas visually.