# TIKZ : How to decorate a \path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, decorations

My question is about drawing a "commutative-type diagram" in mathematics. I would like to integrate an arrow of the type `\rightsquigarrow`, which is described how to be obtained here : [Squiggly arrows in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12678/squiggly-arrows-in-tikz).

The problem is that I uses `\path` to connect the entries of my matrix in `tikz` (because this part comes integrated in a bigger diagram), and i get an error

> "Package PGF Error: I cannot decorate an empty path.".

The code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em, column sep=4em, text height=2ex, text depth=0.25ex]
{ U & U \\};
\path [->, font=\scriptsize, line join=round, decoration={
zigzag,
segment length=4,
amplitude=.9,post=lineto,
post length=2pt}, decorate] (m-1-1) edge node[auto] {F} (m-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

where the decorate part does not work.

Comment: In your example you should also load the TikZ matrix library.

Comment: You're right, i forgot to mention it here !

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could specify the decoration to the path, and give the `edge` the `decorate` option:

```
\path [->, decoration={zigzag,segment length=4,amplitude=.9,
  post=lineto,post length=2pt},font=\scriptsize,
  line join=round] (m-1-1) edge[decorate] node[auto] {F} (m-1-2);
```

[image]

Comment: That's clever, the `decoration` key is set for the entire scope, so you don't have to repeat those for the edge even though it creates a new path. You also don't need the `draw` here because the `every edge` style is equal to `draw` by default. Nice solution!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `matrix` library, otherwise the example doesn't compile. Furthermore, add a `draw` to your path, otherwise there is no line. Finally, replace `edge` with `--` and you should get what you are after.

**Update:** Perhaps I should add why the `edge` does not work and the `--` does. According to the TikZ manual the `edge` operation adds a new path after the main path has been drawn. This new path will have as options `every edge` and the options given to the `edge` operation. Most important, it won't have the same options as the path of which the edge was a part. So if you insist on using `edge` instead of `--` you need to add the decoration information either as an option to `edge` on your path or to the `every edge` style.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the answer, i'm gonna take a look to understand what happens here. I actually am not really familiar with tikz, i only uses it for diagram-making purposes, so \path it's about everything i know :(. I'll take a look it'll probably help me understand it a bit more... :)