# How to create a squiggle arrow with some text on it in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I need to define a new command to create a squiggle arrow with some text on it. Something similar to what `\xrightarrow` command produces but with wiggly arrows as in `\rightsquigarrow`. The length of the arrow should automatically be adjusted to fit the text above it and I do not know how to handle this part in TikZ. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can put your node and decorate a regular arrow going from `(nodename.south west)` to `(nodename.south east)` with a little extra adjustment (Check the manual page 49) but why do you need TikZ for this? Is there any disadvantage of the ones you mentioned?

Comment: @percusse: I guess there is no `\xrightsquigarrow`.

Comment: @Caramdir Aha, that explains it :)

Comment: Related: [Squiggly arrows in tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12678/squiggly-arrows-in-tikz)

Comment: this arrow is in unicode at U+27FF, so it should be in the stix and xits fonts.  the reference i have available gives it the name `\longrightsquigarrow` although `x` would seem more "traditional" than `long` under the circumstances.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As **percusse** mentions in his comment, you can use a node and a decorated arrow; something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,shapes}

\newcounter{sarrow}
\newcommand\xrsquigarrow[1]{%
\stepcounter{sarrow}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=snake]
\node (\thesarrow) {\strut#1};
\draw[->,decorate] (\thesarrow.south west) -- (\thesarrow.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\xrsquigarrow{text}\quad\xrsquigarrow{longer text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The following code contains a new version of `\xrsquigarrow` using the `zigzag` decoration and `\mathrel` to be used in math-mode; it shows a comparison between `\xrightarrow`, `\rightsquigarrow` and `\xrsquigarrow` (some fine-tuning is still required, but I leave that to you):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes}

\newcounter{sarrow}
\newcommand\xrsquigarrow[1]{%
\stepcounter{sarrow}%
\mathrel{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline= {( $ (current bounding box.south) + (0,-0.5ex) $ )}]
\node[inner sep=.5ex] (\thesarrow) {$\scriptstyle #1$};
\path[draw,<-,decorate,
  decoration={zigzag,amplitude=0.7pt,segment length=1.2mm,pre=lineto,pre length=4pt}] 
    (\thesarrow.south east) -- (\thesarrow.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[ 
A\xrightarrow{f} B\quad A\rightsquigarrow B\quad A\xrsquigarrow{f}B\quad A\xrsquigarrow{(f\circ g)\circ h}B
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This definition does not cover the case in which the arrow is to be used in super/sub-scripts.

Comment: Thanks, Gonzalo! This is very similar to what I had in mind. The only difference is the shape of the arrow that does not exactly look like `\rightsquigarrow`. This is important since I want to use the command in math mode and thus, it has to have a clean look. For example, $s \xsquigarrow{OR} t$ means a special operation between $s$ and $t$. The way you have defined the command does not produce a neat output in this setting. I am under impression that the wiggle type must have something to do with the "segment amplitude" and "segment length" of the arrow. Do you have any idea for fixing this?

Comment: @Ali in this case, use the `zigzag` decoration and appropriate values for `amplitude` and `segment length`; I'll give an example in some minutes.

Comment: I customized your command as follows:

`\newcounter{sarrow}
\newcommand\xrsquigarrow[1]{%
\stepcounter{sarrow}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[scale=0.5] (\thesarrow) {\mathstrut#1};
\draw[->,snake=zigzag,segment amplitude=.3mm,segment length=1.3mm,line after snake=.9mm] (\thesarrow.south west) -- (\thesarrow.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}`

This almost produces the right output in math mode, e.g., $s \xrsquigarrow{OR} t$. I am just wondering how I can add some free space between the math symbols and the arrow? Thanks again.

Comment: @Ali please see my updated answer.

Comment: Why is the counter needed for the node name? I seem to be able to replace the node name with a fixed value and everything still works.