# How do I put text over a squiggly arrow?

Tags: arrows, text-decorations

I am currently trying to write text over a squiggly arrow (`\rightsquigarrow`). For normal arrows, I use the `extarrows` package, which provides commands like `\xlongrightarrow` and `\xLongrightarrow` which dynamically stretch the arrow depending on the text length. However, the package does not provide commands for squiggly arrows and I was not able to find another one which does so.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [How to create a squiggle arrow with some text on it in TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60216/how-to-create-a-squiggle-arrow-with-some-text-on-it-in-tikz).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDITED to provide 2 REVISED solutions, one with default symbol set and the other with imported glyphs from `MnSymbol` (not the whole glyph set).

This gives the gist of how you might do it.  The key is finding a symbol that is periodic.  I used the `\sim` character, but there might be better.  Also, I used the `\!` symbol for backspacing, but there may be more precise ways of doing it (you'll note the overlap is not perfect in my example).

I created three commands, for the squiggle, the left squig end, and the right squig end.  One can just repeat invocations of `\squig` to make the squiggle longer.

Or one can use `\squigs` with an argument to get the desired number of squiggles.  Next step was to create the commands that allow text to go over the squiggle.

So the real commands you would in general use are `\rsquigarrow` and `\lsquigarrow`, each with two arguments: the text to go atop the squiggle, and the squiggle length.

**REVISED SOLUTION (DEFAULT GLYPHS)**

This revised solution uses math mode consistently and is compatible with `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%%%%% REMOVE THESE FROM A GENERAL DOCUMENT
\parindent 0pt
\parskip 1ex
\textwidth 2in
%%%%%
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\squig}{{\scriptstyle\sim\mkern-3.9mu}}
\newcommand{\lsquigend}{{\scriptstyle\lhd\mkern-3mu}}
\newcommand{\rsquigend}{{\scriptstyle\rule{.1ex}{0ex}\rhd}}
\newcounter{sqindex}
\newcommand\squigs[1]{%
  \setcounter{sqindex}{0}%
  \whiledo {\value{sqindex}< #1}{\addtocounter{sqindex}{1}\squig}%
}
\newcommand\rsquigarrow[2]{%
  \mathbin{\stackon[2pt]{\squigs{#2}\rsquigend}{\scriptscriptstyle\text{#1\,}}}%
}
\newcommand\lsquigarrow[2]{%
  \mathbin{\stackon[2pt]{\lsquigend\squigs{#2}}{\scriptscriptstyle\text{\,#1}}}%
}
\begin{document}
Here are the commands to make periodic squiggles, with no text above
them:

$2H_2 + O_2 \mathbin{\squig\squig\squig\rsquigend} 2H_2O $\\
$2H_2 + O_2 \mathbin{\lsquigend\squig\squig\squig} 2H_2O $

I can automate a group of squiggles

$\squigs{7}$

Now I will create commands to place text over them

$2H_2 + O_2 \rsquigarrow{exothermic}{7} 2H_2O $\\
$2H_2 + O_2 \lsquigarrow{heat}{3} ~ 2H_2O $
\end{document}
```

[image]

**REVISED SOLUTION (IMPORTING 3 MnSymbol GLYPHS)**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% =============================================
%Import symbols from font MnSymbol without importing the whole package
% =============================================
\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolC}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolC5
  <6-7> MnSymbolC6
  <7-8> MnSymbolC7
  <8-9> MnSymbolC8
  <9-10> MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC10
  <12-> MnSymbolC12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolC-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolC-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolC-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolC-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolC-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolC-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyC} {U} {MnSymbolC}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\MNrhd}{\mathbin}{MnSyC}{76}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\MNlhd}{\mathbin}{MnSyC}{78}
% =============================================
\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolD}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolD}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolD5
  <6-7> MnSymbolD6
  <7-8> MnSymbolD7
  <8-9> MnSymbolD8
  <9-10> MnSymbolD9
  <10-12> MnSymbolD10
  <12-> MnSymbolD12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolD}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolD-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolD-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolD-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolD-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolD-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolD-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolD-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyD} {U} {MnSymbolD}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\MNsim}{\mathbin}{MnSyD}{2}

% =============================================

%%%%% REMOVE THESE FROM A GENERAL DOCUMENT
\parindent 0pt
\parskip 1ex
\textwidth 2in
%%%%%
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\squig}{{\MNsim\mkern-3.6mu}}
\newcommand{\lsquigend}{{\MNlhd\mkern-4.3mu}}
\newcommand{\rsquigend}{{\mkern-1.2mu\MNrhd}}
\newcounter{sqindex}
\newcommand\squigs[1]{%
  \setcounter{sqindex}{0}%
  \whiledo {\value{sqindex}< #1}{\addtocounter{sqindex}{1}\squig}%
}
\newcommand\rsquigarrow[2]{%
  \mathbin{\stackon[1pt]{\squigs{#2}\rsquigend}{\scriptscriptstyle\text{\!\!#1}}}%
}
\newcommand\lsquigarrow[2]{%
  \mathbin{\stackon[1pt]{\lsquigend\squigs{#2}}{\scriptscriptstyle\text{#1\!\!}}}%
}

\begin{document}
Here are the commands to make periodic squiggles, with no text above
them:

$2H_2 + O_2 \mathbin{\squig\squig\squig\rsquigend} 2H_2O $\\
$2H_2 + O_2 \mathbin{\lsquigend\squig\squig\squig} 2H_2O $

I can automate a group of squiggles

$\squigs{7}$

Now I will create commands to place text over them

$2H_2 + O_2 \rsquigarrow{exothermic}{10} 2H_2O $\\
$2H_2 + O_2 \lsquigarrow{heat}{5} ~ 2H_2O $
\end{document}
```

[image]

**LONGTIME ORIGINAL SOLUTION**

This solution is sub-optimal because it mixes text and math modes indiscriminately.  It is also incompatible with `amsmath`, I learned (the contents of `\box0` were getting scrogged by `amsmath`).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\parskip 1ex
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\textwidth 2in
\begin{document}
Here are the commands to make periodic squiggles, with no text above
them:

\newcommand{\squig}{$\scriptsize$\sim$\normalsize$\!}
\newcommand{\lsquigend}{$\scriptsize$\lhd\!$\normalsize$}
\newcommand{\rsquigend}{$\scriptsize\rule{.1ex}{0ex}$\rhd$\normalsize$}
\noindent
$2H_2 + O_2 ~\squig\squig\squig\rsquigend~ 2H_2O $\\    $2H_2 + O_2 ~\lsquigend\squig\squig\squig~ 2H_2O $

Now I will create commands to place text over them

\newcounter{index}

\newcommand\squigs[1]{%
  \setcounter{index}{0}%
  \whiledo {\value{index}< #1}
  {\addtocounter{index}{1}\squig}
}

\newcommand\rsquigarrow[2]{$
  \setbox0\hbox{$\squigs{#2}\rsquigend$}%
  \tiny$%
  \!\!\!\!\begin{array}{c}%
  \mathrm{#1}\\%
  \usebox0%
  \end{array}%
  $\normalsize$\!\!%
}

\newcommand\lsquigarrow[2]{$
  \setbox0\hbox{$\lsquigend\squigs{#2}$}%
  \tiny$%
  \!\!\!\!\begin{array}{c}%
  \mathrm{#1}\\%
  \usebox0%
  \end{array}%
  $\normalsize$\!\!%
}

\noindent
$2H_2 + O_2 \rsquigarrow{exothermic}{7} 2H_2O $\\    $2H_2 + O_2 \lsquigarrow{heat}{3} ~ 2H_2O $

\end{document}
```

[image]