# Game proofs for cryptography

Tags: diagrams

[image: An example of a cryptographic game]

In cryptography a lot of security definitions (IND-CPA, IND-CCA etc.) are represented as games between an adversary and a challenger. Is there an existing package or a simple way to achieve this effect?

Comment: A couple of references that you might find useful: [Drawing network protocols](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54006/13304) and [Replicate this chart using LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103760/13304).

Comment: I found this very helpful, particularly Chapter 4 and 5: ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cryptocode/cryptocode.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you most of the way there.  It's quite a motley assembly of things.  Please feel free to inquire further for elaboration. (Note: I left my original definitions of `\lextlinearrow` and `\rextlinearrow` in place but redefined them.  The original definitions do the overtext in `\tiny` rather than normal fontsize.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\parskip 1ex
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand{\extline}{$\scriptsize$-$\normalsize$\!}
\newcommand{\lextlineend}{$\scriptsize$\lhd\!$\normalsize$}
\newcommand{\rextlineend}{$\scriptsize\rule{.1ex}{0ex}$\rhd$\normalsize$}

\newcounter{index}

\newcommand\extlines[1]{%
  \setcounter{index}{0}%
  \whiledo {\value{index}< #1}
  {\addtocounter{index}{1}\extline}
}

\newcommand\rextlinearrow[2]{$
  \setbox0\hbox{$\extlines{#2}\rextlineend$}%
  \tiny$%
  \!\!\!\!\begin{array}{c}%
  \mathrm{#1}\\%
  \usebox0%
  \end{array}%
  $\normalsize$\!\!%
}

\newcommand\lextlinearrow[2]{$
  \setbox0\hbox{$\lextlineend\extlines{#2}$}%
  \tiny%
  $%
  \!\!\!\!\begin{array}{c}%
  \mathrm{#1}\\%
  \usebox0%
  \end{array}%
  $\normalsize$\!\!%
}

\renewcommand\lextlinearrow[2]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{$\lextlineend\extlines{#2}$}%
  \shortstack{$\mathrm{#1}$\\\addvbuffer[-.7ex -.3ex]{\usebox0}}%
}

\renewcommand\rextlinearrow[2]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{$\extlines{#2}\rextlineend$}%
  \shortstack{$\mathrm{#1}$\\\addvbuffer[-.7ex -.3ex]{\usebox0}}%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent


\begin{tabular}{clc}
{\large Challenger} & & {\large Adversary}\\
picks random k and &&\\
picks random b$\in$\{0,1\}&&\\
\multirow{2}{*}{\addvbuffer[1.1ex]{Repeat n times}\scaleto{\{}{7ex}}&
   \lextlinearrow{P_i}{26} &\\
& \rextlinearrow{\mathbf{E}_k[P_i]}{26} &\\
& \lextlinearrow{M_0, M_1}{26} & picks M$_0$, M$_1$ of equal length \\
& \rextlinearrow{C = \mathbf{E}_k[M_b]}{26} &\\
& \lextlinearrow{b' \in \{0,1\}}{26} &\\
& Attacker wins game if b = b'&
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

See [No \xrightrightarrow[a]{b}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114233/no-xrightrightarrowab/114240#114240) and [How do I put text over a squiggly arrow?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75669/how-do-i-put-text-over-a-squiggly-arrow/99438#99438) for discussion of where I came up with the text over extensible symbol idea.  However, I actually like my current approach of using `\shortstack` better, even though it builds up from the baseline, rather than vertically centering the result.

Comment: thank you, but for some reason \addvbuffer[-.7ex -.3ex]{\usebox0} appears as as -7.ex -.3ex (text) for me

Comment: @Uku Loskit Make sure you have version 3.0 or later of verbatimbox (http://ctan.org/pkg/verbatimbox)

Comment: works with the new version of verbatimbox, thank you!