# Symbol for induces

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am looking for a symbol to use for "induces" (in the mathematical sense, one object can induce another). The symbol leadsto: $\leadsto$ (latexsym package) is of the perfect shape, but it is just too small. I would particularly like to be able to control the length of this arrow, and ideally it would acquire more humps the longer it gets.

Does anyone know of a package that will let me do this?

Comment: See if [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60219/3954) to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60216/3954 does what you need.

Comment: This is perfect! All one needs is \phatom and you can precisely control the length. My question should be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75669/how-do-i-put-text-over-a-squiggly-arrow/99438#99438