# How to typeset path from vertex to vertex in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, graphs

I'd like to typeset a path from a vertex to another vertex similar to this: [image: screenshot of CLRS]

The examples I've found either use TikZ or [does not look](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75669/how-do-i-put-text-over-a-squiggly-arrow) right. Is there a way to typeset a path identically to how it's done in CLRS: Introduction to Algorithms 3rd edition?

Comment: Are you talking about the curved arrow with symbol over it?

Comment: Like this? `$\overset{p}{\rightsquigarrow}$`

Comment: This works well and looks similar, however, the squiggly line has hard corners, not soft. That's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the arrow on your screen shot is `\leadsto` from `latexsym`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,latexsym} 
\begin{document} 
$u\overset{p}{\leadsto} v$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

A potential issue is that `latexsym` overwrites a bunch of symbols. Apart from `\leadsto`, these are

```
\mho,\sqsupset,\Join,\lhd,\Box,\unlhd,\Diamond,\rhd,\unrhd,\sqsubset
```

If you are cool with that, then there is nothing else to do. If you only want this symbol and otherwise the more standard ones, you could copy this symbol from the `latexsym` package and give it a new name:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\ifx\symlasy\undefined 
\DeclareSymbolFont{lasy}{U}{lasy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{lasy}{bold}{U}{lasy}{b}{n}
\else 
\fi
\DeclareMathSymbol\myleadsto{\mathrel}{lasy}{"3B}
\begin{document} 
$u\overset{p}{\myleadsto} v$ 
\end{document}
```

which yields the same output as above.