# Wavy/curvy arrow, with the same oscillation as a tilde

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows, arrow-curve

I'd like to be able to use a wavy arrow, one that is a bit rounder and has a slower oscillation than `rightsquigarrow`: ideally one that has the exact same wave as a tilde, and ends in an arrowhead, and use it in equations in the same way as `a \sim b`.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Edit: `leadsto` from murray's answer is very close. To be even more precise - is there a way to adjoin an arrowhead to a tilde? I'll have a look at Steven's suggestions later today.

Comment: How about this answer? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75669/how-do-i-put-text-over-a-squiggly-arrow/99438#99438  Or this one? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324471/combination-of-arrows-with-and-without-label/327297#327297

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Detexify (http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), one finds the `amssymb` symbol `\leadsto`. Perhaps that's what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\curly}{\mathrel{\leadsto}}

\begin{document}

$a \curly b$

\end{document}
```

[image: \leadsto as math relation]

(*Comment:* Is `\leadsto` already a math relation? I'm not sure yet.)

Another possibility is `\leadsto` from `latexsymb`.

Comment: (I think thats the rightsquigarrow picture you posted.)
Excellent link, thank you! \leadsto is very close to a tilde indeed, hence almost perfect :)

Comment: Actually, package `amssymb` defines `\leadsto` to be the zigzag arrow with sharp angles that is also called `\rightsquigarrow` (other packages, such as `mathdesign` with the option `utopia`, do the same with their own version of the glyph), whereas package `latexsym` defines `\leadsto` to be the smoothly-waving arrow. This is annoying.