# Extensible double lined, squiggle arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I would need an arrow (for math mode) with the following characteristics:

- squiggle (like `\rightsquigarrow`)
- double lined (like `\xRightarrow`)
- extendible (like `\xRightarrow`)

Currently, I am using macros like this...

```
\newcommand{\myDoubleArrow}{\ensuremath{\smash{\xRightarrow[{\scriptscriptstyle \donotsmash{#2} \mkern+4mu}]{ \vbox{\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptscriptstyle \donotsmash{#1} \mkern+4mu}}\vskip -1.0pt} }}}}
```

Do you know any neat possibility to get such an arrow? It should be usable as the command above (however, I only need text on top of the arrow)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does [How to create a squiggle arrow with some text on it in TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60216/how-to-create-a-squiggle-arrow-with-some-text-on-it-in-tikz) helps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possibility using a variation of the answer to [How to create a squiggle arrow with some text on it in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60216/3954):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,arrows}

\newcommand\xrsquigarrow[1]{%
\mathrel{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline= {( $ (current bounding box.south) + (0,-0.5ex) $ )}]
  \node[inner sep=.5ex] (a) {$\scriptstyle #1$};
  \path[draw,implies-,double distance between line centers=1.5pt,decorate,
    decoration={zigzag,amplitude=0.7pt,segment length=1.2mm,pre=lineto,
    pre   length=4pt}] 
    (a.south east) -- (a.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[ 
A\xRightarrow{f} B\quad A\rightsquigarrow B\quad A\xrsquigarrow{f}B\quad A\xrsquigarrow{(f\circ g)\circ h}B
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]