# Squiggly Double-Lined Left-Right-Arrow (i.e. "approximate equivalence")

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

I am trying to create a double-lined arrow pointing to both sides like `\Leftrightarrow` with a squiggly line. The [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) did not seem to contain any such symbol, nor did other (seemingly less comprehensive) lists of LaTeX symbols.

I thought I could adapt the solution from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83086/18853) to a similar question (about a double-lined squiggly arrow pointing into *one* direction. I tried using the information provided in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129917/18853) on how to obtain an arrow pointing to both directions.

As I did not want any text above the arrow, in my first attempt I made the text invisible and just used it to give the arrow its length:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,arrows}

\newcommand\xlrsquigarrow{%
\mathrel{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline= {( $ (current bounding box.south) + (0,-0.5ex) $ )}]
  \node[inner sep=.5ex] (a) {\textcolor{white}{m}};
  \path[draw,implies-implies,double distance between line centers=1.5pt,decorate,
    decoration={zigzag,amplitude=0.7pt,segment length=1.2mm,pre=lineto,
    pre   length=4pt}] 
    (a.south east) -- (a.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
}

\begin{document}

a $\xlrsquigarrow$ b

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this looks like this:

[image: failed attempt #1: left arrowhead rotated]

For some reason, the left arrowhead is rotated by 90° and pointing upward.

Therefore, I decided to remove the obsolte remainder of the original solution (i.e. the node with the text I didn't need) and use absolute coordinates:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,arrows}

\newcommand\xlrsquigarrow{%
\mathrel{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline= {( $ (current bounding box.south) + (0,-0.5ex) $ )}]
  \path[draw,implies-implies,double distance between line centers=1.5pt,decorate,
    decoration={zigzag,amplitude=0.7pt,segment length=1.2mm,pre=lineto,
    pre   length=4pt}] 
    (0,0) -- (0.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
}

\begin{document}

a $\xlrsquigarrow$ b

\end{document}
```

I would have expected that at worst, nothing would be changed (I've just exchanged two coordinates, right?), and at best, that it works now. However:

[image: failed attempt #2: right arrowhead rotated]

Now, the right arrowhead is rotated by 90° and pointing upward!

**Why are those arrowheads rotated and how do I achieve the desired result?**

(Non-Tikz solutions, if any, are welcome, too - I just chose Tikz because I couldn't find a ready-made symbol and this seemed like the most straightforward way. That notwithstanding, I would like to understand why the attempted Tikz solutions shown above behave the way they do.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pre length` is already added, therefore the left arrow looks fine, `post length` fixes the right arrow head. The following example also centers the arrow around the math axis:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  calc,
  decorations.pathmorphing,
  shapes,
  arrows.meta
}

\newcommand\xlrsquigarrow{%
  \mathrel{%
    \vcenter{%
      \hbox{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \path[
            draw,
            >={Implies[]},
            <->,
            double distance between line centers=1.5pt,
            decorate,
            decoration={
              zigzag,
              amplitude=0.7pt,
              segment length=3pt,
              pre length=4pt,
              post length=4pt,
            },
          ]   
            (0,0) -- (14pt,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
      }%
    }%  
  }%
}

\begin{document}
  \[a \xlrsquigarrow b\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Excellent, this works. However, why did the issue change the side depending on whether or not I used the implicit coordinates based on the node?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper `pre` means, where the line starts, and `post`, where the line ends. In case of your implicit coordinates goes from right to left, in the other case from left to right.

Comment: D'oh ... of course. West is left and East is right, geometrically. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way, though it has drawbacks.  It does not support over- or under-text, since the OP indicated no need.  But more importantly, it uses the `\uwave` macro from the `ulem` package, which is only output in periodic intervals.  If the space allowed (optional argument) is not just the precise amount, the spacing on the left side of the arrow (between the `\prec` and the squiggles) will leave a gap.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem,graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\dsar[1][1.95ex]{%
  \mathbin{\scalebox{.7}[1.1]{$\prec$}%
  \scalebox{-1}[-1]{\stackon[-3.7pt]{\buwave{\hspace{#1}}}%
  {\buwave{\hspace{#1}}}}\mkern-2.6mu\scalebox{.7}[1.1]{$\succ$}}
}
\newcommand\buwave[1]{\raisebox{-1.6pt}{\uwave{\raisebox{2pt}{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
$w\dsar x \dsar[3.1ex] y \dsar[4.25ex] z$
\end{document}
```

[image]