# Double-headed squiggly arrow

Tags: arrows

I would like to typeset a squiggly arrow (similar to `\leadsto` or `\rightsquigarrow`) with a double head (similar to `twoheadrightarrow`). I found all kind of posts for straight arrows that provide a solution by combining two horizontally shifted arrows, but this does not work for squiggly arrows, because you cannot superimpose those as easily as straight arrows. I know that what I want is doable with tikzcd (and also plain tikz, I guess), but I would like to use it in usual math mode.

Comment: My answer here, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324471/combination-of-arrows-with-and-without-label/327297#327297 has `\zzigzagarrow`, which is extensible and allows overtext

Comment: I've never commented on a user's avatar before, but Meven, yours is truly beautiful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've never been a fan of clipping but sometimes you just have to go with it...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\twoheadrightsquigarrow}{\rightsquigarrow\joinrel\mathrel{\mathpalette\@twoheadrightsquigarrow\relax}}
\newcommand*{\@twoheadrightsquigarrow}[2]{%
   \clipbox{{.7\width} 0pt 0pt {-.2\height}}{$\m@th#1\rightsquigarrow$}%
}

\begin{document}

$a \twoheadrightsquigarrow b$\par
$\scriptstyle a \twoheadrightsquigarrow b$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle a \twoheadrightsquigarrow b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The four parameters passed to `\clipbox` are the margins in the order left/bottom/right/top. The *negative* top border (then really a padding) is necessary because the arrow head leaks slightly outside the box:

```
\fboxrule.1pt
\fboxsep-\fboxrule
\fbox{$\rightsquigarrow$}
```

[image]

Without the top padding the arrow head would be then partially cut off.

Comment: Dear campa your question is perfectly valid. I have only thought about the idea and providing a restricted code considering that the user, from his reputation, is not a very experienced LaTeX user. I just drew the symbol and declared it as a new command; in fact I have written that my idea can be improved. So you are also allowed to improve it if you prefer my answer. I will be happy to appreciate and add to my mind other very useful information. I have so much appreciate your impeccable answer. I like Trimclip :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple idea done with `tikz-cd` that is possible to improved it. To have the squeeze arrow with two heads I have done a code with this package (see the option `squiggly` recalled with the `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}`). After I have put `column sep=1.2em` to decrease (if you like you can increase the lenght) the lenght of the arrow and I have used `\mkern-10mu` to have a low space between the LHS and RHS.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
$cACCD{\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.2em]{\mkern-10mu}\arrow[r,two heads,squiggly]&{\mkern-10mu}\end{tikzcd}} bVFGHc$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice (+1) but would it be possible to make it scale correctly across math styles?

Comment: @campa You will found the comment below your excellent answer.