# Special Long Arrows

Tags: arrows

I'd like to create a new latex command, called **Surjrightarrow**, i. e. a  `\longtwoheadrightarrow`, but without using `tikz/tikzcd and/or xypic`.

Is it possible? Thank you so much

P.S.: I tried with these

```
\newcommand{\SpecialArrow}[2]{\joinrel{#1}{\!\!\!\!#2}}

%\newcommand{\Surjrightarrow}{\SpecialArrow{\longrightarrow}{\to}}

%\DeclareRobustCommand\Surjrightarrow{\relbar\joinrel\twoheadrightarrow}

\newcommand{\Bijrightarrow}{\SpecialArrow{\lhook}{\:\:\Surjrightarrow}}

\newcommand{\Surjrightarrow}{\longrightarrow\mathrel{\mspace{-21mu}}\rightarrow}
```

but the effects are not much good. My goal is also create a **Bijrightarrow** like up. Thanx again

Comment: Could you provide a small but complete minimum working example, rather than just code snippets?  Does this answer help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324471/combination-of-arrows-with-and-without-label/327297#327297

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}
\newcommand*{\Surjrightarrow}{%
    \mathrel{\ooalign{$\longrightarrow$\cr$\mkern 8.5mu\rightarrow$}}%
}
\newcommand*{\Bijrightarrow}{%
    \lhook\joinrel\Surjrightarrow%
}
\begin{document}
\(A \twoheadrightarrow B\)

\(A \longrightarrow B\)

\(A \Surjrightarrow B\)

\(A \Bijrightarrow B\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: I forget to say that I use stix and the output is not much good (Actually the output of your arrows is the same of mine). How Could I improve? Thx again

Comment: @Puck that would have been a good information to include. Next time, you should add a complete example to your question. I updated my answer to use `stix2`, does it look better? I added a comparison with `stix2`'s `\twoheadrightarrow` as well.

Comment: Ok thank you, but I use stix non stix2.

Comment: @Puck the output is not so different with `stix`. However, `stix` is considered obsolete since 2018 (see the [page on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/stix)), so you should consider switching to `stix2`.

Comment: But I prefer stix instead stix2