# leadsto with text

Tags: arrows, text-decorations

I know that:

```
\[
 A \xleftarrow{\text{this way}} B
  \xrightarrow[\text{or that way}]{ } C
\]
```

will produce:

[image: Example]
Is there a way to have an arrow with text, but with the style of a \leadsto???

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you want the arrow to be as long as the text? If not, you can just use `\underset{\mathclap{\text{this way}}}{\leadsto}`. Otherwise, does [Gonzalo's answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60219/32888) answer your question?

Comment: May be a nice solution is some arrow in TikZ with the `snake` decoration.

Comment: I needed to be as long as text, and Gonzalo's solution seems to break the style, maybe I should change all of them to tikz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I provide a solution with use of [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd). This is easy but will not expand automatically. Just edit the `[column sep=4.5em]` to your needs.

As you had problems with Gonzalo's code, I adapted it slightly for you. Should work now. However, you will not be able to set the label below the arrow. If you are good in Ti*k*Z, you may define more commands like this or set optional parameters in order to modify the placement.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

% code from Gonzalo
\newcommand\xrsquigarrow[1]{%
    \mathrel{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[%
            baseline={(current bounding box.south)}
            ]
        \node[%
            ,inner sep=.44ex
            ,align=center
            ] (tmp) {$\scriptstyle #1$};
        \path[%
            ,draw,<-
            ,decorate,decoration={%
                ,zigzag
                ,amplitude=0.7pt
                ,segment length=1.2mm,pre length=3.5pt
                }
            ] 
        (tmp.south east) -- (tmp.south west);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    }
\newcommand\xlsquigarrow[1]{%
    \mathrel{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[%
            ,baseline={(current bounding box.south)}
            ]
        \node[%
            ,inner sep=.44ex
            ,align=center
            ] (tmp) {$\scriptstyle #1$};
        \path[%
            ,draw,<-
            ,decorate,decoration={%
                ,zigzag
                ,amplitude=0.7pt
                ,segment length=1.2mm,pre length=3.5pt
                }
            ] 
        (tmp.south west) -- (tmp.south east);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    }

\begin{document}
    \[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=4.5em]
    A\arrow[leftsquigarrow]{r}{\text{this way}} 
    & B\arrow[rightsquigarrow]{r}[swap]{\text{or that way}} 
    & C
    \end{tikzcd}\]

    \[
    A \xleftarrow{\text{this way}} B
    \xrightarrow[\text{or that way}]{} C
    \]
    \[
    A \xlsquigarrow{\text{this way}} B
    \xrsquigarrow{\text{or that way}} C
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to write text both above and below the squiggly arrow? Something like $B \xrsquigarrow[\text{above}]{\text{below}} C$ doesn't work.

Comment: @leastaction For tikz-cd just do `\arrow[leftsquigarrow]{r}{\text{this way}}[swap]{\text{or that way}}` For the other approach, please ask another question.