# adjust length of \leadsto arrow to the text above

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, mathtools

I am having really hard time to figure out how to adjust the length of \leadsto arrow in order to match the text above it.
The command I am using is

```
   \newcommand{\transitb}[1]{\stackrel{#1}{\leadsto}_{\pi\gamma}}
```

and here is the output I get:

[image]

I found this as an answer: [leadsto with text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233676/leadsto-with-text)
but I don't want to mess my equation with some tikz stuff.

Is there a simple way to do what I am looking for?

**EDIT:**

Here is the output I get when I try this [How do I put text over a squiggly arrow?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75669/how-do-i-put-text-over-a-squiggly-arrow)
[image]

**EDIT2**

When Trying to use it in beamer within definition block I go the following error:

```
 Missing $ inserted
```

Any thoughts on what could cause this error.

Comment: Maybe this way?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75669/how-do-i-put-text-over-a-squiggly-arrow

Comment: I am trying it but I get errors on compilation

Comment: It is not working I got the output shown in the EDIT.

Comment: I am not sure why it wouldn't work.  However, I will note that, for that MWE, I set both `\textwidth` and `\parskip`, neither of which have anything to do with the operation of the solution.  Their change, however, could wreak havoc with your document, if you tried to copy/paste my result into your document.  So you would want to remove those settings.

Comment: I removed the \textwidth and \parskip setting. Adding them back does not change a thing

Comment: I found that adding `amsmath` causes the behavior you observe.  I will work to fix that.

Comment: Please see revised answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75669/how-do-i-put-text-over-a-squiggly-arrow, which I hope can suit your needs.

Comment: Worked like magic!

Comment: I just provided an additional answer there that uses different glyphs for the squiggles and solid arrow heads.  You might have a look.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes  I am having errors when I try to use it in definition block in beamer!! Error says missing $. Any thoughts on it?

Comment: One thought is `stackengine`, by default, stacks text, not math.  In the cited MWE, I issued a `\stackMath` in the preamble to tell `stackengine` to stack math, not text, by default.  If your application stacks both math and text at different points in the document, one can keep the text stacking as the default, and employ `\ensurestackMath{...}` as needed.