# drawing crazy arrows in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to show that the dependence between two nodes in a tikz picture is not smooth. I thought I would add a crazy arrow like the following:
[image: Crazy arrow]

Of course my drawing is not the best, but you get the idea.
I would like the arrow to have **varying amplitudes and frequencies** to show that the path from node A to node B is quite rough.
Is there a way to do this using tikz? (or a better crazy arrow, more symmetric and periodic?)

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60216/how-to-create-a-squiggle-arrow-with-some-text-on-it-in-tikz

Comment: A squiggle arrow is not that crazy, is it?

Comment: Then define crazy.

Comment: I did, look at the picture...

Comment: `Of course my drawing is not the best`? Well, this doesn't seem a definition.

Comment: You also said "or a better crazy arrow, more symmetric and periodic?" ... symmetric and periodic does not seem crazy to me. That seems ordered. Again, I think you should define crazy. Do you mean random amplitude and varying frequency?

Comment: Yeah, that would be crazy enough, random amplitude and frequency. Like an seismograph plot.

Comment: Do you want ppl duplicate your drawing?

Comment: Of course not, the drawing is terrible. I would like to have an arrow whose paths has varying amplitudes and frequencies. That would convey that going from A to B is not that smooth. But the arrow in the end, even chaotic, needs to look good (not like my awful drawing).

Comment: You might want to edit your question to make it clear so that people don't need to read 20 comments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is another option, using the `sin` and `cos` operations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick,cyan,->,>=latex] 
  (-2,0) -- 
  (0,0) sin (0.5,3) cos (1,0) sin (1.5,-3) cos (2,0) 
  sin (2.5,2) cos (3,0) sin (3.5,-2) cos (4,0)
  sin (4.5,4) cos (5,0) sin (5.5,-4) cos (6,0)
  sin (6.25,1.5) cos (6.5,0) sin (6.75,-1.5) cos (7,0)
  -- ++(1.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A variation on the same theme, but using `plot`:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[cyan,ultra thick]
\draw
  (-1,0) -- (0,0);
\draw[domain=0:2*pi,x=10pt] 
  (0,0) plot (\x,{sin(\x r)}) coordinate (end1);
\draw[shift={(end1)},domain=0:2*pi,x=10pt,smooth] 
  (end1) plot (\x,{2*sin(\x r)}) coordinate (end2);
\draw[shift={(end2)},domain=0:2*pi,x=10pt,smooth] 
  (end2) plot (\x,{5*sin(\x r)}) coordinate (end3);
\draw[shift={(end3)},domain=0:2*pi,x=3pt,smooth] 
  (end3) plot (\x,{0.5*sin(2*\x r)}) coordinate (end4);
\draw[->,>=latex] (end4) -- ++(1,0);  
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess I can add as many frequencies as I would like to. Thanks!

Comment: @aaragon You're welcome! I added another option to my answer that could be of interest for you.

Answer (score 15):

TikZ has a path decoration called `random steps`. You should be able to get sufficiently crazy paths by adjusting the segment length and amplitude values. For something periodic (and much less crazy), you can use the `snake` decoration, which has similar adjustable parameters. See section 24 in the TikZ documentation.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-stealth,decorate,decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=4pt,pre length=2pt,post length=3pt}] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[-stealth,decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=3pt,pre length=2pt,post length=3pt}] (0,-0.5) -- ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! This is sort of what I'm looking for and I will definitely use it if I don't get the type of arrow I would like to have. Any ideas on how I can get something that looks more "periodic"?

Comment: @aaragon Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Your second option, though periodic, it doesn't look that crazy. Gonzalo's option is what I am looking for. But I appreciate your effort a lot erik, I wish I could give two correct answers here.

Comment: is it perhaps possible to make the random steps only go forwards and not backwards?

Comment: @intStdu This may answer your question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/477495/24974