# Combine tikz curve with random variation

Tags: tikz-pgf, random, tikz-decorations

I would like to combine a curve defined with `\draw` with a random variation along the path.

So far I have found quite some interesting discussions on tex.SE like [How to draw Brownian motions in tikz/pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59926), [How to fix the trajectory of Brownian motions which generated by the "rand" function with tikz in beamer frames](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60059), and (thanks to Kpym, I have overseen this) [Simulating hand-drawn lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39296), but they do not work as expected.

Using tikz-decorations looks promising, but only for relatively straight curves.

The following MWE gives this result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5mm,y=5mm,decoration={random steps,segment length=3mm,amplitude=1mm}]
  \draw[thick,green] (0, 1) -- (14.5, 1);
  \draw[thick,red,decorate,rounded corners]   (0,-0.5) -- (14.5,-0.5);
  \draw[thick,blue,decorate,rounded corners] (0, 0.5) -- (1,0.5) -- (1.5,-4) -- (2,-3.5) -- (3.5,-2) -- (14.5, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The third (blue) `\draw` command produces not the result that I try to get - even the red line has a "hickup" at about 75% of the way in x direction.

According to the tikz-manual the reason  is: *The end of each step is perturbed both in x- and in y-direction by two values drawn uniformly from the interval [−d,d], where d is the value of amplitude.* This conflicts with the curved option where variing only the y value should give the desired output. Since the plots describe the change of a value in time they may not turn towards the negative x direction.

Is there any way to restrict the `random steps` decoration to manipulate only the x value but not y? The alternative would be to overlay a curve by a random distortion at descrete intervals like brownian motions...

Hoping the results are somehow stable (which conflicts with the idea of random shifts - lol) there's no real need to control seeds...

Comment: How about `\draw (0,0)
\foreach \x in {1,...,10}
{   -- ++(0.1,rand*0.1)
};` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59927/121799 ? Or could you try to make your question a bit clearer? Your code has `rounded corners`, which is the reason for the "hick-ups" but you mention these not in your question.

Comment: @marmot `\draw (0,0) \foreach \x in {1,...,10} { -- ++(0.1,rand*0.1) }` will give me a basically straight line, right? So this would result in loosing control over the general shape. Working for the red line, but not for the blue. The `rounded corners` are used to make the line smoother... Without them the interval of variation has to be reduced which makes the line too "waggy"...

Comment: `rounded corners` and `smooth` are two very different things You *can* draw a smooth curve but this is *very* different from `rounded corners` where you get the same radius (unless you make additional efforts). Anyway, I added an answer that should answer "Is there any way to restrict the random steps decoration to manipulate only the x value but not y?". If that's not what you want, it would be great if you could clarify your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an answer to the question: can one have random steps in the y direction? The answer is yes, all one needs to do is to copy the definition of random steps and to set the `x` shift to zero.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{random y steps}{start}
{%
  \state{start}[width=+0pt,next state=step,persistent precomputation=\pgfdecoratepathhascornerstrue]{}%
  \state{step}[auto end on length=1.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
               auto corner on length=1.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
               width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{
      \pgfpointadd
      {\pgfpoint{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0pt}}
      {\pgfpoint{0pt}{rand*\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    }
  }%
  \state{final}
  {}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5mm,y=5mm,decoration={random y steps,segment length=3mm,amplitude=1mm}]
  \draw[thick,green] (0, 1) -- (14.5, 1);
  \draw[thick,red,decorate,rounded corners]   (0,-0.5) -- (14.5,-0.5);
  \draw[thick,blue,decorate,rounded corners] (0, 0.5) -- (1,0.5) -- (1.5,-4) -- (2,-3.5) -- (3.5,-2) -- (14.5, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course one can draw a smooth random curve. At this point, this has to go in two steps.

1. `\path[decorate] <path>;`
2. `\draw[<options>] plot[variable=\x,samples at={1,...,\arabic{randymark}},smooth] (randymark\x);`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\newcounter{randymark}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{mark random y steps}{start}
{%
  \state{start}[width=+0pt,next state=step,%
  persistent precomputation={\pgfdecoratepathhascornerstrue%
  \setcounter{randymark}{0}}]{
  \stepcounter{randymark}
  \pgfcoordinate{randymark\arabic{randymark}}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  }%
  \state{step}[auto end on length=1.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
               auto corner on length=1.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
               width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]
  { \stepcounter{randymark}
    \pgfcoordinate{randymark\arabic{randymark}}{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{rand*\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
  }%
  \state{final}
  {
    \stepcounter{randymark}
    \pgfcoordinate{randymark\arabic{randymark}}{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5mm,y=5mm,decoration={mark random y steps,segment length=3mm,amplitude=1mm}]
  \path[decorate]   (0,-0.5) -- (14.5,-0.5);
  \draw[red,thick] plot[variable=\x,samples at={1,...,\arabic{randymark}},smooth] 
   (randymark\x);
  \path[decorate] (0, 0.5) -- (1,0.5) -- (1.5,-4) -- (2,-3.5) -- (3.5,-2) -- (14.5, 0);
  \draw[blue,thick] plot[variable=\x,samples at={1,...,\arabic{randymark}},smooth] 
   (randymark\x);
  \path[decorate] (4,4) circle(3cm); 
  \draw[orange,thick] plot[variable=\x,samples at={1,...,\arabic{randymark}},smooth] 
   (randymark\x);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that this is certainly not the first post that draws a smooth random curve through a path, there are several earlier posts, including [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49961), [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70018), the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334341/121799) and the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/475141/121799).

Comment: May be you can make reference to this questions : [TikZ two-blocks matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70018), [Simulating hand-drawn lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49961) and [Create xkcd style diagram in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74881) ?

Comment: @marmot the crazy thing about marmots is that they come up with solutions to questions that i can not make clearer at the moment. I'd like to vote +3 and will accept the answer even if the result is not exactly what I need. But since I'm no 'do-it-for-me' I'll go through the decorations engine to enhance both your answer to fit my needs and myself :-)   Helped a lot as starting point. Thx!

Comment: @Kpym Yep, thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Kpym Absolutely. Thanks! I added a few references. If you give me a hint why https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74881 is to be added, I will be happy to add it, too.