# Squiggly line over equations

Tags: math-mode, equations

I would like to draw special lines over parts of my equations, basically the functionality that `overline` provides. However, I do not want a straight line, but a squiggly line, as in `rightsquigarrow`.

I have also tried `widetilde` (not exactly squiggly, but at least it is something), but it cannot be made arbitrarily long, which is a requirement for me.

A typical usecase would be

```
\begin{align*}
\oversquigline{ABCD} \\
\oversquigline{A^i}
\end{align*}
```

It should look something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60219/2417) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [How to create a squiggle arrow with some text on it in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60216/how-to-create-a-squiggle-arrow-with-some-text-on-it-in-tikz/60219#60219), I have come up with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes}

\newcounter{sarrow}

\newcommand\oversquigline[1]{%
\stepcounter{sarrow}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={snake,amplitude=0.2ex},baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box)}]
\node (\thesarrow) {$#1$};
\draw[->,decorate] ([xshift=1ex,yshift=-0.2ex]\thesarrow.north west) -- ([xshift=-1ex,,yshift=-0.2ex]\thesarrow.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Here is an example:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
x=&\oversquigline{ABCD} \\
y=&\oversquigline{A^i} + \oversquigline{B_x^i} + \oversquigline{a}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It works reasonably well, but is a bit ugly for "a"...