# Long Squiggly Arrows in LaTeX

Tags: arrows

Is there some way for me to get long squiggly arrows of length comparable to `\longrightarrow` or `\longmapsto` in `LaTeX`?

Comment: You can make them with TikZ. See [Squiggly arrows in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12678/2693).

Comment: How straightforward will it be to write a script for squiggly arrows that can be used inside math environment without much problems (not having to care about alignment and positioning)?  If it can be straightforward, then I can try writing a command for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you don't mind using Xy-pic, you can type

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[cmtip,all]{xy}
\newcommand{\longsquiggly}{\xymatrix{{}\ar@{~>}[r]&{}}}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

$X \longrightarrow Y$

$X \longmapsto Y$

$X \longsquiggly Y$

$X \xymatrix@C=1.5em{{}\ar@{~>}[r]&{}} Y$

\end{document}
```

and it will give you

[image]