# Long Squiggly arrow in Beamer

Tags: arrows

I would like to use a long squiggly arrow in beamer. I already found a similar question here:
[Long Squiggly Arrows in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99017/long-squiggly-arrows-in-latex?rq=1),
but it doesn't seem to work in my case.

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Have you seen this answer? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12678/squiggly-arrows-in-tikz

Comment: Console output says:

`! No room for a new \dimen .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}

fi 
l.137 ... \csname newdimen\endcsname \scratchdimen
? `