# Artin's squiggly arrow?

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows

Is there a package containing the squiggly arrow that Artin uses in his *Algebra* text? It looks like:[image: Artin arrow]

I've seen some of the options using tikz on here, but they aren't quite the same.

Comment: What makes this squiggly arrow so special? With the `decorations.pathmorphing` library (and `arrows`) I can do `\draw[decorate, decoration={zigzag, segment length=+2pt, amplitude=+.75pt,post length=+4pt}, -stealth'] (a) -- (c);` which looks quite good to me.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I'm writing something pertaining to this text and want the notation to be consistent.

Comment: The options I have seen so far, including the link from @egreg, are similar, but not quite the same. If I could get the same, I would be delighted.

Comment: Can you give us the specification of the arrow? What is important? Otherwise it looks just like a squiggly arrow to me.

Comment: this arrow is in unicode at U+27FF, so it should be in the stix and xits fonts.  the reference i have gives it the name `\longrightsquigarrow`.

Comment: There also is `\longrightsquigarrow` inside of the `mdsymbol` package (it is a little shorter)

Answer (score 26):

`amssymb` has one called `\rightsquigarrow`, but you may find that it's not long enough:

```
\[a\rightsquigarrow\overline{a}\]
```

[image]

Comment: There is also a "speaking" name for that arrow: `\leadsto`

Comment: See also here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12678/squiggly-arrows-in-tikz/442036#442036

Comment: I need a \leftsquigarrow but it doesn't seems to be degined amssymb, what could I do?

Comment: @Dabed See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195025/how-to-get-the-opposite-direction-of-rightsquigarrow)

Comment: thank you very much