# How to get the opposite direction of \rightsquigarrow?

Tags: symbols, arrows

The command `$\rightsquigarrow$` produces a funny looking arrow that points to the **right**.
I want to get an arrow of the same style but points to the **left**.

One would think that `$\leftsquigarrow$` will do the job, but LaTex saids it is an *Undefined control sequence*.

Am I missing something here? How do you get an arrow like `$\rightsquigarrow$` but points to the **left**?

Comment: Not sure of the exact packages, but bizarrely I found myself in a situation where not only was `\rightsquigarrow` defined, but `\leftrightsquigarrow` was _also_ defined, and yet `\leftsquigarrow` was not!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not `amsmath`command, but one can obtain it through `txfonts` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}

$\leftsquigarrow$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note though that `txfonts` may change the font.

Answer (score 14):

Here's the way, reflecting the arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\leftsquigarrow}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\reflect@squig\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\reflect@squig}[2]{%
  \reflectbox{$\m@th#1\rightsquigarrow$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$A\rightsquigarrow B\leftsquigarrow C$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\providecommand` is because some math font packages may have the symbol (it is with `newtxmath`, for instance).

Answer (score 9):

`mathabx` also has:

[image]

As to `MnSymbol`, it has a whole tribe:

[image]

`MdSymbol` has about as many:

[image]