# How to draw wavy line in the sentence

Tags: text-decorations

How to draw wavy line in Latex simply in the sentence line of an article paragraph.

I know there is a underline `\uwave` comment, but I like to have just wavy line itself, without anything above.

I am looking for something such that `\uwave{...}` without ....

Adam below provides an answer, but I would like to have a way to shift the underwaveline to the normal position like --- or - - -?

Please help!

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12678/squiggly-arrows-in-tikz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use `\hspace` inside of `\uwave` with the length that you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}

\uwave{\hspace{1cm}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Note that `normalem` retains the normal treatment of `\emph`asized text. See p. 1 of the [`ulem` documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/ulem/ulem.pdf).)

---

### Edit

If you want the wavy line in the middle of the text, you can do:

```
A\raisebox{0.5em}{\uwave{\hspace{1cm}}}B
```

Which produces:

[image]

You could wrap it in a macro:

```
\newcommand{\middlewave}[1]{\raisebox{0.5em}{\uwave{\hspace{#1}}}}
```

And then you can do:

```
\middlewave{1cm}
```

---

### Edit 2

If you want to use this inside of `\caption`, you will need to `\protect` it. (See [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)) Here's a complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{mwe} % for a complete Minimal Working Example

\newcommand{\middlewave}[1]{\raisebox{0.5em}{\uwave{\hspace{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A\protect\middlewave{1cm}B}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to shift the underwaveline to the normal position like --- or - - -?

Comment: You could use `\raisebox{1ex}{\uwave{\hspace{1cm}}}`

Comment: Looks like we had the same idea, @corporal. `:)`

Comment: @Idear see my edit.

Comment: somehow I compile with the bug if we put this comment line into the Figure \caption{   \middlewave{1cm}     }. Do you know why?

Comment: Even if I try: \caption{ ... \raisebox{0.5em}{\uwave{\hspace{.5cm}}} ... } has a problem in the caption of Figure. Do you know why?

Comment: Outside the Figure \caption{}, there is no problem at all for using your comment \middlewave{1cm}. Why?

Comment: @Idear see my update.

Comment: @ Adam, you are really an expert!!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13469/discussion-between-idear-and-adam)

Comment: how to make it just slightly wavy?

Comment: @Thumbolt There won't be an easy way to do that with the solution offered here. I would take a look at TikZ because you'll probably have to draw your own wavy line in order to make it less wavy. [Nicer wavy line with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25678/32888) might be a good place to start.